# Windows 10 24GB and SSD takes 5 minutes to Boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

My i5 desktop Windows 10 Pro is taking over 5 minutes to boot--with a SSD.  I have run the xBootMgr profile and it shows winlogon.exe starts immediately  and for 2.50 min of the 5.83 min boot time, there is nothing--other process or disk activity going on during this period.  Any suggestions has to how to determine what winlogon is waiting for?

[image: xBootMgr Summary]

Comment: Domain or workgroup?

Comment: This PC is part of a Domain.

Comment: share the ETL (compressed as 7z) so that I can analyze it

Comment: Try to boot with your network cable disconnected and see if it helps.

Comment: The ETL file is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/glu4ov9i8bb0g9x/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISK_IO_INIT%2BDISPATCHER%2BDRIVERS%2BFILE_IO%2BFILE_IO_INIT%2BNETWORKTRACE%2BPERF_COUNTER%2BPOWER%2BPRIORITY%2BREGISTRY_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: Unplugging the cable has no impact on boot time.  I should have made it clear that the 5.83 minutes is to the point I am able to log in.  I would expect any domain impact would occur after this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookig in the generic Events table for Events from the `Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon` provider I can see that the `CreatePrimaryTerminal` task takes over 200s to finish.

[image]

[3 years ago I saw this, too, and here font files caused](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158252-trace-why-windows-8-boots-shutsdown-or-hibernates-slowly/?do=findComment&comment=1056920) such a long delay. Look if this also applies to you.

But it must have someting to do with fonts. Looking at the callstack shows, that the CreatePrimaryTerminal function loads fonts:

```
Line #, Process, Stack Tag, Stack, Thread ID, Count, Weight (in view) (ms), TimeStamp (s), % Weight
9, , ,   winlogon.exe!WinMain, , 107, 106,712051, , 0,01
10, , ,   winlogon.exe!CSession::CreatePrimaryTerminal, , 107, 106,712051, , 0,01
11, , ,   winlogon.exe!CreatePrimaryTerminal, , 107, 106,712051, , 0,01
12, , ,   |- user32.dll!CreateWindowStationW, , 106, 105,712051, , 0,01
13, , ,   |    user32.dll!CommonCreateWindowStation, , 106, 105,712051, , 0,01
14, , ,   |    user32.dll!NtUserCreateWindowStation, , 106, 105,712051, , 0,01
15, , ,   |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd, , 106, 105,712051, , 0,01
16, , ,   |    win32kfull.sys!NtUserCreateWindowStation, , 106, 105,712051, , 0,01
17, , ,   |    win32kfull.sys!xxxCreateWindowStation, , 106, 105,712051, , 0,01
18, , ,   |    |- win32kfull.sys!xxxInitTerminal, , 102, 101,694054, , 0,01
19, , ,   |    |    win32kfull.sys!xxxLW_LoadFonts, , 102, 101,694054, , 0,01
20, , ,   |    |    win32kfull.sys!xxxbEnumerateRegistryFonts, , 102, 101,694054, , 0,01
21, , ,   |    |    win32kfull.sys!xxxbEnumerateRegistryFontsInternal, , 102, 101,694054, , 0,01
22, , ,   |    |    |- win32kfull.sys!xxxAddFontResourceW, , 96, 95,668687, , 0,01
23, , ,   |    |    |    win32kfull.sys!xxxClientAddFontResourceW, , 96, 95,668687, , 0,01
```

The latest trace shows that you still have other fonts installed (Marketing Script Inline, Marketing Script, Microsoft JhengHei, CordiaUC, Teamviewer, Rage Italic, La Bambda, Quixley, Pump Demi).

So remove really all 3rd party fonts.

// Edit 2016-08-24

The second trace shows a long delay in Boot-SessionInit/SMSSInit-Phase:

[image]

> The SMSSInit subphase begins when the kernel passes control to the
>   session manager process (Smss.exe). **During this subphase, the system
>   initializes the registry, loads and starts the devices and drivers
>   that are not marked BOOT_START**, and starts the subsystem processes.
>   SMSSInit ends when control is passed to Winlogon.exe.

I looked at the delay and see that the Init/enum of Serial devices (COM port connected devices) is slow:

[image]

If you don't need COM port, disable the COM port in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: I checked my fonts and while there were many (635) there were no encrypted fonts.  I selected all of them and did a delete (i have a backup) and all except 86 uninstalled.  I rebooted and basically same boot time.

Comment: An interesting anecdote.  I ran msconfig and chose diagnostic startup.  Boot was the same if not a bit longer.

Comment: create a new boot trace: **xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags BASE+LATENCY+DISPATCHER -stackwalk profile+CSwitch+ReadyThread -resultPath C:\TEMP** this captures delay/wait info. Maybe I see why the boot is hanging creating the terminal

Comment: The link to the new etl file is https://www.dropbox.com/s/51zzf22odmhg4wu/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: update the logitech camera driver and disable malwarebytes. In the trace I see that you use a Seagate Baracuda and no SSD.

Comment: Interesting.  The original drive was a Segate but it is gone and replaced with a OCZ-Trion SSD.

Comment: Interesting.  Originally there was a Seagate HD in the PC but I did upgrade to a OZ SSD.  Checking the Device Manager, it showed the ST1000 disk drive instead of the SSD.  Checking the logitech site, I had the latest driver.  So here is what I did.  I uninstalled the ST100 drive and rebooted and it and the right HD driver installed.  Then I uninstalled Logitech and Malwarebytes.  Then I reran a xbootmgr.  The new trace is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/fm6dbgq4f9j6npc/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER_2.zip?dl=0

Comment: I Posted new details. share the new trace with the registry/file read data

Comment: Here is the .etl file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsjd4ghjy82z2n2/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER%2BREGISTRY%2BFILE_IO%2BFILENAME_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: you still have several other fonts. remove all 3rd party fonts

Comment: Andre,  your initial diagnosis was right on!  Used the Font CP to remove Fonts but that made no difference. So I went to the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Window NT\Current Version\Fonts and found there were still 100's listed.  I backed-up the key, then deleted all but the basic fonts.  Then rebooted and viola!!  boot time is now 75 seconds.   so then I went back and reinstalled all my fonts (600+) and rebooted and still 75 seconds!!  There must have been a font in the registry that was  pointing to a file(s) that did not exist  so there may be a timeout before retrying or something. Thanks Much!

Comment: Andre, help!  My PC attempted the Win 10 Anniversary update and it failed.  I assume there was an issue with my video card.  After the failure, Win 10 reverted to the prior release and ever since my boot times are longer than ever -- nearly 10 minutes.   I removed all the fonts again and it made no impact.  Can you take a look at the etl file and see what is cooking?  

I ran an xbootmgr trace and it is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kvamglgq7e2pke/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: now sessioninit is slow, I'll take a look at it this evening.

Comment: @Andywt I posted what I saw

Comment: Andre,I did disable the serial port in the BIOS, but it made no difference.  Here is the new etl file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kvamglgq7e2pke/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: I see ACPI.sys delays and USBport.sys. remove the external USB drives that you have attached.

Comment: Andre, I removed all usb devices except keyboard and no change.  Here is the etl: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kvamglgq7e2pke/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: the SSD is also heavily used (100% diskIO) at the time where the hang happens. also disable the SUPERFETCH service and look what happens. I see a lot of Unknown (0x0) calls which are superfetch calls

Comment: Disabled Superfetch service and no change to boot time.  Here is etl: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kvamglgq7e2pke/boot_BASE%2BLATENCY%2BDISPATCHER_1.zip?dl=0

Comment: I still see a lot of diskIO with Unknown (0x0) calls . try to update to v1607 and loo if the issue is gone

Comment: Upgrading to 1607 is what started this problem.  Before the upgrade we had 1 minute reboots but after the upgrade failed and once it finally reverted back I started getting the 10 minute reboots.

Comment: get the 1607 ISo and try again to update to 1607: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557

Comment: were you able to update to 1607? Is boot now faster?

Comment: no.  i got the iso and did the update and it booted up.  it took a while so i booted again to create an etl and it never came up   just stalled a black screen.   after multiple attempts and no success, i reverted back to prior release   havent had a chance to try again

Comment: create an image of your current Windows and install 1607 from scratch (clean install, so format the HDD and reinstall the cache software)