# What is the default download folder for the Windows 10 Anniversary Update tool?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607

Recently I started to download the Windows 10 Anniversary Update onto one of my machines via the [official tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history) provided by Microsoft.

With 100% of the actual update being downloaded, I wonder:

1. If it is possible to copy the files to another (licensed!) installation for the intended purpose of a system upgrade?
2. Where in the system (i.e., in which directory) the actual update files are stored?

Would be happy for official/verified answers, as I'd like to safe time prior to upgrading other machines as well, without the need to download all that data again (multiple times).

*Edit-1:*

It does not seem to be the directory `C:/Windows10Upgrade` as this contains only around 16MB of data. I would expect around 2-3 GB somewhere on my disk, as the Anniversary Update is known to download about 3 GB of upgrade files.

*Edit-2:*

I don't want to *create* or *download an ISO*. I'd like to know where the downloaded data is stored on my disk and if it is possible to *reuse* it for the purpose of system upgrades.

Comment: If you click the "get the anniversary update now" button, it allows you to save it anywhere you want. Yes you can use the update file on any PC. The file is small because it is a stub installer, once you run the file it downloads the correct files depending if you have 32 or 64bit windows. If you want the full ISO see this link....http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/download-windows-10-anniversary-update

Comment: @Moab - You did not understand my question. I got the updater and downloaded that already. If you launch it, it'll download a lot of data to your disk. I'm look for the destination of that downloaded files.

Comment: votes are anonymous, no I did not.

Comment: @Moab if the ISO is an answer for you to this question (which has two parts) consider adding it as an answer, instead of a comment. Maybe it's also worth an upvote, as it shows a clear research interest in the topic.

Comment: It really does not answer the question "What is the default download folder " but is more of an alternative to get the full installer. This is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Moab I do like your suggestion, however, I'm really looking for a way to evacuate what I've already downloaded to one of my machines and reuse that.

Comment: get a clean ISO and store the ISO where you have most space: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557

Comment: I have nothing further to say on this subject.  I have removed my comments as they were just additional noise.  I wish you luck in solving your problem.  I unfortunately don't have answer to your question, at this time, that I would be proud of submitting.  I yield to better words smiths them myself.

Answer (score 1):

The setup file for Windows 10 Anniversary Update is in 'C:/Windows10Upgrade' as an ESD file format. While downloading the update through the tool, it keeps on saving the downloaded materials in the ESD file. So, don't worry if you had to cancel the download in between. It will always resume even after you cancel the download in the tool. If you are quite apprehensive of this then you can COPY the 'Windows10Upgrade' folder in an external storage device as a backup. When you start the download again, I'm sure it will resume again. But if it doesn't then you can paste the backed up folder in the C: and then the download will resume.

After you install the Update the ESD install file is usually treated as a temporary file by Windows. So, it deletes to allow more space. If you want to keep a backup then you should keep it before installing the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I just did my update 2 days ago, and there's a hidden folder in C: called $WINDOWS.~BT.  It still has some files from when I did my original upgrade from Windows 7, but the vast majority of the folders and files have time stamps consistent with when I installed the anniversary update.