# Cannot upgrade to Windows Anniversary Edition unless activated

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

It seems you cannot simply upgrade to the Windows Anniversary Edition unless you *activate* your windows before. Is there a workaround which allows the upgrade while delaying the activation?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just activate first? Or perhaps get the ISO that has the anniversary update already installed, and install it from scratch?

Comment: I guess using Media Creation Tool would help too, worth a try.

Comment: @Aganju - In order to unerstand the restrictions you are under, why is your installation, not activated?  Is it because it is a closed system, and the system must be activated by phone, knowing this information will allow us to come up with an answer that you can actually use.

Comment: I am experimenting with various virtual machines, and they are not activated because of the cloning. I plan to activate the ones I want to keep using - some day soon - and have the keys ready, but not yet.I understand that activation solves the issue; I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: Curious if you've already tru from the Windows machine that is not activated, from the **Run As Administrator** command prompt to run, **`slmgr -rearm`** and then try the upgrade method afterwards? Give that a shot when you get a chance if you've not already and report back your findings. I'll be happy to add this as an answer if it works to resolve your issue.

Comment: download the 1607 ISO an do the upgrade: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, after `slmgr -rear` it asks me to reboot, and then the same thing happens.