# Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade stuck

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607

This post is valid for the Upgrade initiated by the Windows10Upgrade28084.exe , with which I have had success so far already on 2 other Laptops.

Please, tell me how to get some info of the reason on Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade stuck at ab. 32% done, just after the second restart at 30%, during the actual final update process phase?

This Laptop is freezing with no picture on display and power-on, and, not reacting to any mouse/keyboard signals, forever, until an emergency shutdown, pressing power-off for 6sec.

There is no hints for the problem on Windows System/Application logs.

I have been checking and applying for this several hints from net, but still always the same result on some 3 consecutive Upgrade trials ...

Note, that anyway one prerequisite has shown to be essential for this Upgrade, namely KB3176493, which is a part of Windows 10 Update to 1511 10586.545 level.

Comment: How long did you let it set at 30%, let it set overnight.

Comment: @Moab OK, once  several hours during the night, and powering-off on the morning, and others some shorter periods, twice seen just passing ab. 32% done, and then got freezing with a grey display and not anymore reacting to any mouse/keyboard signal.

Comment: get a clean ISO (http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount it, run setup.exe and select upgrade/keep apps and data

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK, thanks for the hint. FirstlyI thought the available ISO is the same as for the basic Windows 10 1511 version, which I already have on an USB stick, but now, after checking the downloadable file, it's for the version 1607, even on my own language, great! I'll download/copy it to an USB stick and try the Upgrade in the evening.

Comment: OK, the Windows 10 1607 ISO is now downloaded and copied into a bootable USB stick with rufus v2.10. As a comment, the Upgrade procedure shouldn't be started booting from the USB stick, but, booting normally from disk to Windows 10, and then starting the setup.exe from the USB stick, with the option to save programs, files and settings.

Comment: OK, now the Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade procedure has once again tried on this (3rd and older) laptop, from the ISO on an USB stick, but sorry, with exactly with the same result as previously already 3 times ... Everything running smoothly until the main update phase 32% done, and then suddenly freezing with blank grey display and power-on ... This time with the ISO setup.exe, after reversing the install, the following splash error window did pop-up:

Comment: -> Windows 10 couldn't be installed.  
Computer has been returned to the state, on which it was just before beginning the install.  
0x1900101 - 0x30018  
Installing failed at phase FIRST_BOOT, because an error occurred during function SYSPREP . So, what/where to look/investigate next?

Comment: Sorry, probably however -> 0xc1900101 - 0x30018 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this question and topic of mine, please see the subsequent question and thread on this -> [Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade error 0xc1900101 - 0x30018 referring to SYSPREP](https://superuser.com/questions/1113521/windows-10-anniversary-upgrade-error-0xc1900101-0x30018-referring-to-sysprep) , and my solution answer down ab. last there.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a laptop. Update failed twice at about 32%. The laptop automatically rebooted to the unupdated Win 10.
Tried a trivial approach.
Went wired instead of wireless. Update failed at about 40%.
On the fourth attempt - turned off other computers on the router.
The update completed successfully.
Do not know whether this approach or just being persistent was the key to ultimate success.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comment, the 32% is exactly the same with me. But, despite several and still some more disablings, I haven't ever got further, and all the time having just the LAN cable connection, USB's, two WLAN's etc. and AntiVirus, Firewall etc. were all completely disabled. Regarding other computers on the router, probably having some other on it for side-working during the Upgrade ... let's have one more trial in the evening with this one alone.

Comment: Sorry to inform, but this hint didn't work for this laptop, still exactly the same result, stuck on 32%.and freezing etc.  Please, take a look to the one step ahead question of mine on this topic -> http://superuser.com/questions/1113521/windows-10-anniversary-upgrade-error-0xc1900101-0x30018-referring-to-sysprep .