# Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade error 0xc1900101 - 0x30018 referring to SYSPREP

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, sysprep, windows-10-v1607

OK, please, following you have an updated one step ahead question regarding my first question post on the title.

The question now is, how possibly get some info or tracing/debug on, which possible reason is leading to this error referring to SYSPREP.

In the net I found several posts for this, and the following link do have quite exact instructions what to look at and try, and I have also been following most of them, except maybe one-two, which I now will still follow on a next Upgrade trial in few hours.

-> https://techjourney.net/windows-10-upgrade-first_boot-failure-with-error-0xc1900101-0x30018/

Here you have a summary of the background info for this case:

- Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade is stuck at ab. 32% done, in a minute after the second (despite named as FIRST_BOOT) restart at 30%, during the actual final update process phase, with blank grey display and power-on
- after an emergency power-off in a quarter or so, the Upgrade trial will got reversed and following error splash window will pop-up:

  > ## We couldn't install Windows 10
  >
  > We've set your PC back to the way it was just before you started installing Windows 10.
  >
  > 0xC1900101 - 0x30018 
  >   The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with an error during SYSPREP operation
- the laptop is some 7yrs old with dual-core AMD 1.9GHz 32-bit, memory 3GB, and has been working great with Windows 10 Pro (updated from 8.1) since 9 months
- I know there is outdatings with e.g. display driver, now run with the basic MS one, and Wi-Fi driver etc., but several of the risky devices and also software have been disabled during the Upgrade trials

I hope someone could help me some step ahead on this.

Comment: If you are updating a previous question, just EDIT that question instead of asking another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade stuck](http://superuser.com/questions/1112248/windows-10-anniversary-upgrade-stuck)

Comment: @Xavierjazz Please, hope you may accept this as an updated one step ahead question regarding my first question post on the title.

Comment: @magicandre1981 OK, thanks for the edit, aimed too to do something like that, but didn't so far at all know how to do it, maybe some day in the future ...

Comment: It is extremely confusing, when questions have solutions to problems, describe in the question.  If its a problem you had, that wasn't the problem your asking about, just remove that problem from the question and upvote the answer that helped you.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, do not really understand your point, I think this type of question, not getting any answers or solution, I'll still myself have to go on chasing for some progress for it, and also think maybe it's useful to tell about the proceedings and findings I have noted for it ...

Comment: If you make edits to your question, just make edits, you don't need to indicate in the question itself you made edits. Keep your question focused, if you have other problems in addition to the problem you described in the question, ask a different question to solve those problems.  Keep the question clean, it appears you had other problems, but solved those on your own.  Doing these simply things, when you ask question makes your question more likely to be viewed as being helpful to the community.

Comment: "Did also try a DISM cleaning on the SSD, on which popped-up errors' I may open another thread. Sorry, found just a solution on this -" - Statements like this just make your question more confusing to the reader.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, now some unnecessary text on this question deleted ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, sorry, I'm quite a newbie on here, so, do not yet know all the habits or fine-tunings needed to post here, but anyway have something to tell, if interested ...

OK, got this Windows 10 Upgrade problem finally solved!  It didn't get solved at all on the  SYSPREP direction, but by DISM RestoreHealth with the right install.esd first converted into .wim a.s.o, see details on my post, quite down there in [Windows 10 DISM error: 0x800f081f](https://superuser.com/questions/951538/windows-10-dism-error-0x800f081f/1116756#1116756) .  This procedure did repair the problematic parts of the previous Windows 10 Pro 1511 10586.545 . (Note, also the sfc /scannow did now run all clear from the beginning to the end.)

Please, note also some of the possible other key points, pre-cautions, disablings etc., described on the link above up on this thread.

Now I did follow the Upgrade procedure quite intensively, noting several interesting points during it, with the most critical point, from the restart at 29/30% continuing in ab. 33secs to the 32%, and now this time passing it, and continuing on smoothly up to 100% a.s.o, to the lucky end, with the all-new version 1607 14393.82 ! Great!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and solved it. 
In the past I changed my wifi-adapter from Sitecom to Netgear. Now i found out that the Sitecom-software was still running on my computer. If you remove the old wifi-adapter software your problem could be solved. It worked for me. 
If the above doesn't work try this:
I downloaded the ISO-file from Microsoft, and burned it to a DVD:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
(Choose: "Download tool now" and burn the ISO-file on a DVD)
Then remove the USB wifi-adapter from your computer, and turn off your antivirus-software temporarily. It is not necessary to remove the software entirely. Restart your computer. Goodluck !  (Greetings from Frank, Amsterdam)

Comment: OK, thanks for your advices, I'll check them tomorrow when at the site.

Comment: OK, one more trial today, now first after a successfull  DISM RestoreHealth with the right install.esd -> .wim, and, the Upgrade to 1607 succeeded!  Next step would have been this your answer/suggestion, so, I noted it as an useful one. Now have to run to a next case, so, will come back soon with some more details on this successfull step.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using Windows Update in installing Windows 10, you can implement the following:

Open the Command Prompt window by pressing Windows Key + X. Select Command Prompt (Admin) from the menu.

Stop the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. In order to do this, Type or Copy and Paste the following commands one at a time:
NOTE: Don’t forget to hit Enter after every command.

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
```

Rename the Catroot2 and SoftwareDistribution In order to do this, Type or Copy and Paste the following commands one at a time:
NOTE: Don’t forget to hit Enter after every command.

```
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
```

Restart the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. In order to do this, Type or Copy and Paste the following commands one at a time:
NOTE: Don’t forget to hit Enter after every command.

```
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

Type Exit in the Command Prompt then close the Command Prompt window then restart the computer. If that fails, you can try the suggestions listed [in this article](http://errortools.com/windows/fix-error-code-0xc1900101-0x30018-in-windows-10/).

Comment: OK, thanks for this procedure, it's a working one, and have been using it lately a few times on problematic Windows 7 Update cases.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION to this NIGHTMARE . GOT MY WINDOWS 10 updated to Version 2004 FINALLY! (and debugging recommendation for all further windows update issues)
TLDR; under Windows features

If you really want you can run SetupDiag which would hunt your computer for log files and output a file called SetupDiagResults.log, but I'd suggest you try the following steps.
-Went into "turn windows features on or off" type windows features in start menu (or start menu-->run -->optionalfeatures) -->from there I unchecked .Net Framework 3.5(including .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
If that doesn't work try running .Net framework repair tool

OxC1900101 - 0x30018 The installation failed in the FIRST BOOT phase with an error during SYSPREP_SPECIALIZE operation

was having log file showing this.
"Error: Found AdvancedInstaller Generic failure. Last Phase: Pre SysPrep Last Operation: Upgrade security Executable: SMConfigInstaller.exe Exit Code: 3222072836 Phase: 38 Mode: Install (first install) Component: WCF-GenericCommands, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64 Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information. " FreeBooter mentioned this: SMConfigInstaller.exe belongs to product Microsoft® .NET Framework. If you can update .NET Framework or uninstall it and try upgrade.

Ran SetupDiag (downloaded it) as administrator and it analyzed logs files and finally one of which had a good summary under the file it generates in same folder as the exe called "SetupDiagResults.log", look for the word "Error:" ? when I didn't run as admin, it seemed to output just empty files.

debugging step (you can provide your SetupDiag log on bleepingcomputer forums under windows 10 and they may be able to assist) ..

-Went into "turn windows features on or off" type windows features in start menu (or start menu-->run -->optionalfeatures) -->from there I unchecked .Net Framework 3.5(including .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
If that doesn't work try running .Net framework repair tool

Comment: Wow, who knew afters days of wondering it's as simple as uninstalling .NET 3.5! Does anyone know why did it stuck the update?

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating 1903/1909 for over two months. Studying winupdate logfiles(Panther logs) I found few device drivers giving errors. Uninstall RtkBluetooth driver, I do not have a bluetooth in this laptop. Also deleted SpeedFan service.

```
(dos console as administrator)
sc query  RtkBtFilter
sc delete RtkBtFilter
sc delete speedfan
```

Find registry(regedit.exe) to delete remaining references to RtkBtFilter and Speedfan services.

Remove `Internet Information Services` and `Windows Process Activation Service` in `Windows features On or Off` settings app. Delete `c:/windows/system32/inetsrv/` folder after removing IIS service.

Install .NET 3.5 framework `c:\> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All`, I already had NET4.8 so now have two framework releases.

Download `Windows 10 Update 1909` tool from Microsoft and write image to USB memory stick. Run setup.exe from usb stick and choose an option `Do not download updates while upgrading`. Installation still gave a blue-screen-of-death `Critical process died`. After system rebooting itself it however kept update going forward and finally Windows 10 Feature 1909 was completed.

Forcing `Check for windows updates` in Settings app was able to download incremental patches so finally all good. My old documents and applications survived.