# Windows 10 Update failing

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I've had Windows bug me about updating a few times over the past couple months, and every time it's failed (ran for 30 minutes or so and then shut the system down and give me "undoing changes made to your computer" when I turned it back on). I finally ran the ISO and it did the same thing, but gave me this info on where the update failed.

> 0xC1900101 - 0x30018
>
> The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with an error during SYSPREP_SPECIALIZE operation

- Image of the error:

[image]

Does anyone know any possible remedies to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade error 0xc1900101 - 0x30018 referring to SYSPREP](https://superuser.com/questions/1113521/windows-10-anniversary-upgrade-error-0xc1900101-0x30018-referring-to-sysprep)

Comment: Provide all relevant information from this [tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) additional diagnostic cannot be performed without this information

Comment: What operating system are you trying to update from?   Windows 7 perhaps?   Go to Microsoft.com, search for the Windows 10 Upgrade Adviser, download this and run it. What does the Upgrade Adviser (Assistant) tell you?