# Windows 10 Insider ISO download

Tags: iso-image, windows-10-preview, windows-insider

I just wanted to download the latest version of Windows 10 Insider Preview from https://insider.windows.com/, but when I click on the "PC" button, it takes me to [an error website](https://www.microsoft.com/library/errorpages/smarterror.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/en-us/software-download/windows10) which says

> We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.
>   The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available.

Is it just broken for the moment or don't they provide the ISO for download any more?

I only have the very first version of Windows 10 on DVD and must have cleaned up any ISOs to save disk space.

I am not looking for the latest official version. I am participating in Windows Insider since 01/2015 and I definitely want the Insider build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get a clean ISO of the Windows 10 Anniversary update?](http://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-anniversary-update)

Comment: @Ramhound: I am definitely looking for an Insider Build. I was able to download the ISO but I could not identify it as being the wrong one.

Comment: It's version 2607, not a RS2 build, which is what your looking for.

Comment: *Version 1607 not 2607..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the Windows Insider ISOs from [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced) after logging in with your Microsoft account that is assigned to the Insider Program.

[image]

[image]

When builds move to slow ring, new ISOs for newer RS2 Builds will be published on this website.

Now Microsoft provides Build 14931 from RS2 branch as ISO on the page:

[image]

Comment: Try changing the agent on your browser, to a mobile device, the link provide by this answers author is correct.

Comment: go to https://insider.windows.com/, logon with your insider account, open a new tab with the provided url

Comment: "hy Microsoft would make links dependent on the user agent." - If you are running a browser on Windows they redirect you from one page to another and then offer you the upgrade tool, if you were running something other then Windows, they let you get the .ISO without a redirection.  This was for a different page, but it was a suggestion, to rule out some weird redirection issue.

Comment: @Ramhound I see this ISO page on a Windows Laptop

Comment: You will have to take my word what I went through to get an ISO on July 30th

Comment: @ThomasWeller does it work for you now?

Comment: go to insider.windows.com, logon with your insider account. is this still possible?

Comment: OMG, I got it working: http://superuser.com/a/1121681/105621

Comment: nice to hear this.