# Windows Insider Program: enrollment doesn't let me finish

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

When I try to enroll my Windows 10 for the Windows Insider Program I

- navigate to Settings > Update and security > Windows Insider Program
- click 'Get Started'
- choose the account I want to connect with
- choose the branch I want content from
- review the privacy statement and program terms
- click Restart Now

Here is the Problem:
after the restart I have to do the steps from above all over again.

So I am stuck in this very annoying loop. Can anyone get me out of that?

specs: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1709, OS Build 16299.192 (most recent)

Comment: You do understand you don't immediately start receiving updates once you change your channel right?  In any event, if you don't want to wait, download the current Windows Insider Preview build ISO and from within Windows, launch the setup.

Comment: yes I know that I wont receive updates right away. but I have been waiting for almost 3 months now and nothing happened. cannot take that long to have any kind of updates coming my way, right?

Comment: You will want to use my suggestion of using the ISO in that case.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but wouldn't that mean that I would have to do a clean install and lose all pre-existing stuff? or can I do an upgrade using the ISO?

Comment: No, if it required a clean installation, I would have told you that in my original comment.  I suspect you need the [ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1114730/windows-10-insider-iso-download?rq=1)

Comment: Worth pointing out once you are in the RS4 channel, you won't be able to revert to your previous installation and will be stuck there until at least March 2018.