# Windows 10 Pro 64 bit version 1607 fails to install KB3176938 with 0x800F0922

Tags: 64-bit, windows-update, windows-10-v1607

So this is a Windows 10 Pro 64 bit version 1607 system, Insider edition on a slow ring. Some days ago it was repeatedly failing `KB3176934` with the same `0x800F0922`. I didn't find out the root cause and how to prevent it. My purpose is to find other who has exactly this same problem and figure out a solution. If someone already has a solution - even better.

Looking at the CBS directory, back from 08/26/2016 when the `KB3176934` was failing I see a 22GB (!) log file. It seems like that there was "some" deadlock:

```
...
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Session: 30539793_3012262845 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Opened cabinet package, package directory: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\, sandbox location: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\, cabinet location: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\Windows10.0-KB3176934-x64-EXPRESS.cab, manifest location: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\update.mum
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Resume and Download Job
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Apply Deltas Provided In File
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    Ended DPX phase: Apply Deltas Provided In File
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Apply Deltas Provided In File
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    Ended DPX phase: Apply Deltas Provided In File
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    CJob::Resume completed with status: 0x0
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  DPX    Ended DPX phase: Resume and Download Job
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Exec: Asynchrous operation, session completes later
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsExecutionCommunication, level: 130, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsExecutionCommunication, level: 130, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsSession, level: 66, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsExecutionCommunication, level: 130, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsSession, level: 66, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsExecutionCommunication, level: 130, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsExecutionCommunication, level: 130, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsSession, level: 66, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
2016-08-26 20:18:37, Info                  CBS    Lock: Error found, inverse lock order, current lock held: CCbsExecutionCommunication, level: 130, lock attempted: CCbsWorkerQueue,  level: 60. This will lead to a potential deadlock
...
```

This goes on for more than an hour taking up 22 GBs - talk about a tiny deadlock!

Moving onto 08/30/2016:

```
...
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  CBS    Opened cabinet package, package directory: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\, sandbox location: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\, cabinet location: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\Windows10.0-KB3176934-x64-EXPRESS.cab, manifest location: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\update.mum
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Resume and Download Job
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Apply Deltas Provided In File
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    Ended DPX phase: Apply Deltas Provided In File
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    CJob::Resume completed with status: 0x0
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    Ended DPX phase: Resume and Download Job
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    Extraction of file: update.ses failed because it is not present in the container (\\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\3717a62e3772d26d381fa9aea49eed42\Windows10.0-KB3176934-x64-EXPRESS.cab).
2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    DpxException hr=0x80070002 code=0x020109
```

2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  CBS    Not able to add file to extract: update.ses [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
    2016-08-30 15:16:03, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Resume and Download Job

...happening multiple times and...

```
...
2016-09-01 19:28:39, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2016-09-01 19:28:39, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change completion for package: Package_for_KB3189031~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.0, current: Installed, original: Absent, target: Installed, status: 0x0, failure source: Not Applicable, failure details: "(null)", client id: WindowsUpdateAgent, initiated offline: False, execution sequence: 93, first merged sequence: 93, pending decision: PendingAvoided_DelayQueueSideStepped, primitive execution context: Interactive Flight: False
2016-09-01 19:28:39, Info                  CBS    The store corruption status report is incomplete. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-09-01 19:28:39, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2016-09-01 19:28:39, Info                  CBS    FinalCommitPackagesState: Completed persisting state of packages
...
```

whole bunch of this:

```
...
2016-09-02 14:07:33, Info                  CSI    000006cf    One of the components setting this value is Microsoft-Windows-shell32, version 10.0.14393.103, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2016-09-02 14:07:33, Info                  CSI    000006d0    Previously seen component setting this value is Microsoft-Windows-shell32, version 10.0.14393.103, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2016-09-02 14:07:33, Info                  CSI    000006d1 Warning - Overlap: Registry value collision found under key \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllSyncRootObjects\shell\ErrorResolution\ for MultiSelectModel, only one component should set this value
...
```

This is maybe not critical:

```
...
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS    Progress: UI message updated. Operation type: Update. Stage: 0 out of 0. Percent progress: 10.
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 7, phase: 2, result 0, inf: input.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 8, phase: 2, result 0, inf: stornvme.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 9, phase: 2, result 0, inf: usbvideo.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 0, phase: 3, result 0, inf: acpi.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 1, phase: 3, result 0, inf: wnetvsc.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 2, phase: 3, result 0, inf: wstorvsp.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 3, phase: 3, result 0, inf: wvpcivsp.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 4, phase: 3, result 0, inf: BthLEEnum.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 5, phase: 3, result 0, inf: bth.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:58, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 6, phase: 3, result 0, inf: xinputhid.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 7, phase: 3, result 0, inf: input.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 8, phase: 3, result 0, inf: stornvme.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 9, phase: 3, result 0, inf: usbvideo.inf
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS    DriverUpdateInstallUpdates failed [HRESULT = 0x80070bc2 - ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS    Doqe: System reboot required.
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS    Perf: Doqe: Install ended.
2016-09-02 14:07:59, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Non-critical driver operations completed successfully.
...
```

Trying some sid `S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139` which is not present in my system. And we are onto writing `WER`, which looks like has trouble in itself:

```
...
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CSI    000002f4 Performing HKCU for sid: S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Error                 CSI    000002f5 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #72233# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg = (AllowAccessDenied), key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY), oa = @0x46f1fbe60->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[78]'\Registry\USER\S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 1864350776)[gle=0xd0000034]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Error                 CSI    000002f6@2016/9/2:21:09:01.262 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(5238): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey expression: (null) [gle=0x80004005]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160830221525.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Startup: Changing logon timeout to a static timeout: 10800000
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160827053046.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160827031613.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160826035948.cab to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160826022443.cab to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Could not get active session for current session file logging [HRESULT = 0x80004003 - E_POINTER]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Error                 CSI    000002f7 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #72232# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg = 0, key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY), oa = @0x46f1fbe60->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[78]'\Registry\USER\S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 1864351756 [gle=0xd0000034]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Error                 CSI    000002f8@2016/9/2:21:09:01.684 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(5238): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey expression: (null)[gle=0x80004005]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160830221525.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160827053046.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160827031613.log to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160826035948.cab to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160826022443.cab to WER report.
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Could not get active session for current session file logging [HRESULT = 0x80004003 - E_POINTER]
2016-09-02 14:09:01, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
...
```

seems like that the lack of this `sid` fails the installer, which is the final error code in the Event Logs: `0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED`:

```
...
2016-09-02 14:13:05, Error                 CBS    Startup: Failed to process advanced operation queue, startupPhase: 0.  A rollback transaction will be created. [HRESULT = 0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED]
2016-09-02 14:13:05, Info                  CBS    Setting ExecuteState key to: CbsExecuteStateInitiateRollback | CbsExecuteStateFlagAdvancedInstallersFailed
2016-09-02 14:13:05, Info                  CBS    SetProgressMessage: progressMessageStage: -1, ExecuteState: CbsExecuteStateInitiateRollback | CbsExecuteStateFlagAdvancedInstallersFailed, SubStage: 0
2016-09-02 14:13:05, Info                  CBS    Progress: UI message updated. Operation type: Update. Stage: 1 out of 1. Rollback.
...
```

Then with the recent `KB3176938` I see similar errors:

```
...
2016-09-02 16:15:33, Info                  DPX    Extraction of file: update.ses failed because it is not present in the container (\\?\C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download\7dab6589581c4510df5e184be35f7c59\Windows10.0-KB3176938-x64-EXPRESS.cab).
2016-09-02 16:15:33, Info                  DPX    DpxException hr=0x80070002 code=0x020109
2016-09-02 16:15:33, Info                  CBS    Not able to add file to extract: update.ses [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-09-02 16:15:34, Info                  DPX    Started DPX phase: Resume and Download Job
...
```

craziness

```
...
2016-09-02 19:05:26, Info                  CSI    000006d1 Warning - Overlap: Registry value collision found under key \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AllSyncRootObjects\shell\ErrorResolution\ for MultiSelectModel, only one component should set this value

2016-09-02 19:05:26, Info                  CSI    000006d2    One of the components setting this value is Microsoft-Windows-shell32, version 10.0.14393.103, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2016-09-02 19:05:26, Info                  CSI    000006d3    Previously seen component setting this value is Microsoft-Windows-shell32, version 10.0.14393.103, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
...
```

Same non critical driver mishap:

```
...
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS    Progress: UI message updated. Operation type: Update. Stage: 0 out of 0. Percent progress: 11.
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 9, phase: 2, result 0, inf: usbvideo.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 0, phase: 3, result 0, inf: acpi.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 1, phase: 3, result 0, inf: wnetvsc.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 2, phase: 3, result 0, inf: wstorvsp.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 3, phase: 3, result 0, inf: wvpcivsp.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 4, phase: 3, result 0, inf: BthLEEnum.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 5, phase: 3, result 0, inf: bth.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:39, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 6, phase: 3, result 0, inf: xinputhid.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 7, phase: 3, result 0, inf: input.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 8, phase: 3, result 0, inf: stornvme.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS            INSTALL index: 9, phase: 3, result 0, inf: usbvideo.inf
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS    DriverUpdateInstallUpdates failed [HRESULT = 0x80070bc2 - ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS    Doqe: System reboot required.
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS    Perf: Doqe: Install ended.
2016-09-02 19:05:40, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Non-critical driver operations completed successfully.
...
```

seems like again the lack of this `sid` causes the rollback:

```
...
2016-09-02 19:06:43, Info                  CSI    000002f4 Performing HKCU for sid: S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139
2016-09-02 19:06:43, Error                 CSI    000002f5 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #72233# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg = (AllowAccessDenied), key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY), oa = @0x649a27c4f0->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[78]'\Registry\USER\S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 2586297032)[gle=0xd0000034]
2016-09-02 19:06:43, Error                 CSI    000002f6@2016/9/3:02:06:43.692 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(5238): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey expression: (null) [gle=0x80004005]
...
```

So maybe the key is the `sid` `S-1-5-80-1448039036-2013904622-3830678473-3382385916-2632875139`, but I cannot find anything about it with web searches.

The log files (CBS.zip):
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=23A52F09515EBE7%216609&cid=023A52F09515EBE7

[image: System About]

---

Downloaded the Anniversary Update (`Windows10Upgrade28084.exe`) but it presents an empty dialog only with an Exit button.

[image]

Maybe the problem is that this `KB3176938` is always in the "installed and restart needed" phase, so I'm not able to install other things? Just guessing...

Trying to force install the KB3176938 after manually downloaded the `CAB` file.

---

Manually installing KB3176938 form a manually downloaded cabinet was not successful either. I was thinking maybe to start the install from safe mode, but the error comes really at the end of the install procedure, the computer restarted and again went to almost 100% progress. I feel like I'm in a 22-catch situation. First I'd like to stop the windows update from forcing this update.

---

See answer. After the repair with `Windows10_InsiderPreview_Client_x64_en-us_14393.iso` I got KB3176934 and a couple of more updates. Seems to work fine now. Looking back, maybe at some point I did (or the system offered?) the anniversary update? Maybe that's not a good idea for an Insider Win10.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45066/discussion-on-question-by-csaba-toth-windows-10-pro-64-bit-version-1607-fails-to).

Comment: Since the incident above I got into another update revert loop around the beginning of October. After a week of agony a user discovered that it was caused by an Xbox service. Note, that I don't have an Xbox. Microsoft prepared an installer for the registry fix for that problem. The installer only worked for the second try but solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last way to repair a Windows is called [Repair Install/Inplace Upgrade](https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/).

[Download the 1607 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO via double click on the ISO. Now navigate to the virtual DVD drive, run `setup.exe` and select to keep all applications/settings

[image]

This repairs Windows and should fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, this should reset the system to a clean slate (but keeping all installed software and everything). Great that Windows 10 offers that. Since I'm an Insider I went with the current latest `Windows10_InsiderPreview_Client_x64_en-us_14393.iso` and this brought me to `14393.105` build.

Comment: the 105 is also offered for non insiders now. if you want to stay at 1607, change to Release Preview or Production Ring, otherwise you'll get RS2 Builds soon.