# My computer still has not received the Windows 10 anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1607

My computer still has not received the Windows 10 anniversary update and it has been weeks since release. I keep checking Windows Update but nothing is coming through.

What can I do?

Comment: Does anybody know why it's been rolled out progressively? Is it a pure logistics issue to keep Microsoft server loads manageable?

Comment: That and so that if there's a major issue (eg: update causes 5% of computers to crash), they are notified of it early and can halt the upgrade for everyone else

Comment: have you tried to get the ISO and run setup.exe to upgrade?

Comment: Google and see if your specific model has compatibility problems with Windows Anniversary Update.  Make sure that you've backed up your files before running the update from the ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the issue if you download the media creation tool, which will tell you what windows has not: your drive is probably too full. The installation requires about 20 GB of free space to operate (some of which will be used for new features, some of which is just for temp files). Free up your hard drive, and the update should start within a few days. You can also then force it to start by running the media creation tool.

Comment: Maybe sometimes, but not always. My boot drive has 83GB free of 120GB - still no update [not that I'm in any hurry]

Comment: oh, that's interesting. Maybe that wasn't my problem after all then. It would be interesting to see if windows ever did notify me that I was missing out due to drive space

Comment: @Blaine You would have been pushed the update eventually and it would have failed.  How detailed the failure would have been is likely the same detail for any Windows update failure

Answer (score 3):

I just started the manual installation from this website when I upgraded:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history

This allows you to get the update without having to wait for it to come through the normal channels.

Click: "Get the Aniversary Update now" button

Comment: as mentioned, this is exactly what i did

Answer (score 2):

Download the [Windows 10 v1607 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO by doing a double click on the ISO, run `setup.exe`, select Upgrade

[image]

and now `keep apps & settings`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

OK, I have found this MCT-method the best for several deferring Windows 10 Anniversary Upgrade cases:

- download the appropriate ISO x86 or x64, or even both the same time, to a 8/16GB empty USB stick with Windows 10 Media Creation Tool
- note! just to ensure the USB stick, new or used, is 100% totally empty, first clean it with -> diskpart command on an elevated prompt, but, be extremely careful with the subsequent list/select/clean etc. functions, not to ruin your actual disks/partitions with the clean function
- do the Upgrade install inside the present Windows 10 starting it with the setup.exe on the root or appropriate folder on the USB stick

Instead of the USB stick, you may also download the ISO to your HDD and burn it into a DVD.

Comment: As i mentioned, the media creation tool works just as well, considering itś only 5 MB and runs in the OS

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way I found is using the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant.
But it seems Microsoft removed it from its website..

Found a copy on a German PC magazine website:
http://www.chip.de/downloads/Windows-10-Update-Assistent_97600470.html

Hint: Be sure to use "Manuelle Installation" instead of the big Download button!