# Couldn't finish my windows update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, ubuntu-16.04

I am having Dell Inspiron N-5010 Laptop 64-bit architecture, and I have installed windows 10 Version 10586 32-bit side-by Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.
I want to upgrade windows 10 version 10586 to version 14393. Every time if i check for updates from settings, it starts to downloads the updates and ask to restart after downloading finished and after restarting no changes had happened. I have checked with my desktop which is having the same windows version (without ubuntu) for the same updates and there is no issue with it. So I used "Windows 10 Update Assistant".

But it didn't help me, So how to solve this issue?

and i have seen this ".esd" file in the time of the updating progress in one of the local disk. Do i have to use that file in any of the way?

Comment: get a clean 1607 ISO, mount it, run setup.exe, select upgrade/keep everything and see what happens. Before doing this, make a complete image of your system so that you can restore it in case something goes wrong. here the link to the ISO: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557

Comment: any update? Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yep it does worksbut some software which were installed previously didn't work. But thanks

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer. For your non working applications, ask the developers for an update to support v1607

Comment: @magicandre1981 but the grub loader is not seen at starting, it is directly starting with windows 10

Comment: this is expected. Windows doesn't care for other boot loaders. Reinstall GRUB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Upgrade to the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607), get the [1607 ISO from Microsoft](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO via double click on it, run the `setup.exe` on the virtual DVD drive, now select Upgrade

[image]

and next select `Keep personal files and apps`

[image]

This upgrades Windows 10 to the Version 1607 and keeps all installed Windows Applications.