# Dism restorehealth source files not found

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, dism, repair-install

I have several problems on my pc and want fix win10 without reinstalling all apps. When I run:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
```

I get Error 87. With:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /CheckHealth
```

I get a message, that it can be repaired. So, I ran:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

And get this error: 0x800f0906. Source files not found. (The PC is connected to the internet and online). I tested it with a local image:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:C:\Users\Lars\Desktop\wrc\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

And get the same error (0x800f0906). The file exists on my harddrive with that name. The same happens with a mountained Image or an install.esd file.

```
sfc /scannow
```

Says, that all is fine. In windows update, I get this error: 0x80070002.
In chkdsk, all is fine, too.

I have read a lot about that topics. The program folder location was not changed. I get the same errors, when I run these commands and safe mode, or after a clean boot.

The Logs can be found here:

[Dism](http://pastebin.com/nvCwRfSZ)

and [cbs](http://pastebin.com/8MsZswef)

Any help is welcome

Comment: share the CBS.log and the DISM.log so that we can see which files are corrupted

Comment: @magicandre1981 Please check my update. I added links.

Comment: any update? Have you starte the cmd as admin? does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues. You miss several files from the German language pack and from Update KB3200970:

```
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Microsoft-OneCore-Connectivity-Bluetooth-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-@E~10.0.14393.0
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-OneCore-Connectivity-Bluetooth-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~0.0.0.0 Microsoft-OneCore-Connectivity-Bluetooth-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0   
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-base-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~0.0.0.0    Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-base-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0  
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-mincore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~0.0.0.0 Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-mincore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0   
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0   Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0 
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Multimedia-MMECoreBase-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0  Multimedia-MMECoreBase-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Multimedia-MMECoreBase-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~0.0.0.0    Multimedia-MMECoreBase-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0  
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Multimedia-MMECoreBase-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0 Multimedia-MMECoreBase-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0   
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Package_1031_for_KB3200970~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0  Package_1431_for_KB3200970~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.5
(w) CBS Package Index Package Missing   0x80070490  Package_1550_for_KB3200970~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0  Package_1150_for_KB3200970~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64z~10.0.1.5
(w) CBS Watchlist Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-OneCore-Connectivity-Bluetooth-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0  Microsoft-OneCore-Connectivity-Bluetooth-WOW64-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0   
(w) CBS Watchlist Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-base-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0 Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-base-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0  
(w) CBS Watchlist Package Missing   0x80070490  Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-mincore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0  Microsoft-OneCore-CoreSystem-WOW64-mincore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0   
(w) CBS Watchlist Package Missing   0x80070490  Multimedia-MMECoreBase-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~0.0.0.0 Multimedia-MMECoreBase-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~de-DE~10.0.14393.0
```

Download the [German 1607 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), the [Update KB3200970](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3200970) and use [DISM to add the Update KB3200970 to the Install.wim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/add-or-remove-packages-offline-using-dism).

Now point to the modified `install.wim` while trying to restore the damaged files.

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:C:\Win10WithKB3200970\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

Comment: When I try to make the install.wim writable I get an error, "Access denied". Other Tabs in that dialog Box are missing, too. I only have "General" and "Details". "Security", etc. are missing. What shall I do now?

Comment: what do you do? use DISM to mount the WIM, add the CAB of the update to the mounpath, use DISM unmount /commit to save changes to the new WIM

Comment: I followed the steps in the tutorial, you have posted a link to. When trying to do this:  `Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:G:\sources\install.wim /Name:"Windows 10 Pro" /MountDir:C:\Users\Lars\Desktop\repair_new`, i get the error, that the files is not writable.

Comment: have you started the cmd.exe as admin before running the DISM command?