# WiFi and Trackpad problems on Lenovo G510

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo G510 laptop with 4GB RAM and Intel i5 4200M 2.50GHz processor.

Recently, my laptop disconnects every time from my home WiFi network. In addition, my trackpad sometimes freezes, and I can't move the mouse, but I can still control my laptop. Sometimes it's even worse, and the whole computer just freezes.

I thought maybe it is an old driver issue, but since I have Windows 10 32-bit, I cannot download any drivers for my computer from Lenovo's website, since they only have drivers for Windows 10 64-bit.

Is there any operation I can do in order to fix this? It is really urgent, since this is my main computer and most of my work is online...

Comment: Your processor model is 64 bit architecture refer this [Intel page](http://ark.intel.com/products/76348/Intel-Core-i5-4200M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz). Can you please tell what is the reason for using 32 bit OS?

Comment: @vembutech This is the OS came installed on my laptop

Comment: Check the system by running [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html). Try also an external WiFi adapter if you have one accessible.

Comment: See also if there are useful errors in the Event Viewer (see [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-3128616/windows-event-viewer.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You should install the 64Bit [Windows 10 with a clean ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), followed by all [drivers from Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g510-notebook?beta=false) and look what happens.

If you still have freezes, press the CAPS LOCK key during the freeze. If the status light on the keyboard toggles, you have a software/driver based freeze. If the light doesn't toggle the hardware was froozen.

If you have a software based freeze, update all software/drivers until you found the causing driver. If you get HW based freeze, do RAM test and make sure the battery/AC adapter work fine. Such power issues can also cause freezes.

Comment: First of all, I realized from your answer that this is a software problem. About the 64 bit version, I don't want to do that now, since I will have to do a clean install, which is something I would like to avoid of.

Comment: with 32Bit, you loose memory and security. Some techniques are better in 64Bit.  Why do you want to avoid a reinstall?

Comment: Yes, I know that. The problem is that I want to avoid the clean install. I don't want to lose all my files since this is my main computer

Comment: backup all data to cloud/external HDD and here you don't loose anything

Comment: He does lose all installed applications and their settings.

Comment: @harrymc settings can be synced in cloud ;)

Comment: How is it done ?

Comment: @harrymc signin with a Microsoft account and in settings you can select which data get synced

Comment: I usually avoid Microsoft login, but it surely would work only for the simplest cases and not for applications not in the Store. I'm not against your answer - just ensuring that the poster is forewarned.