# ESD file After by mistake cancellation of clean installation tool(win 10)

Tags: windows-8, windows-10-upgrade

I am using windows 8 single language.
I was installing windows 10 on my pc by using Mediacreation tool (official tool by microsoft).

It was on 99%. believe me!

But unfortunately It got cancelled or just disappeared from the screen.
I searched for its file but I got nothing but Just a ESD file which was not there before. It was of size 2.88GB. What this File is?
Can I start the upgradation anyhow by this from where it was left over...
PLz help.
Thanks!

Comment: Start over... it's the only safe way to complete the installation.

Comment: It took me whole day for that process..@DrMoishePippik

Comment: If you no longer have installation media you can create a disk image (.iso file) with that ESD file. That ESD file is the install disk in a compressed and encrypted form, but it's easy to make it usable. Look here: http://m.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-iso-file-using-installesd-image

Comment: Yes, I believe you... upgrading Windows may take **days** (as opposed to installing Ubuntu, for example, which takes about 1/2 hour). After upgrade, you'll spend many more hours loading Windows Updates.

Comment: Is any other way to use that ESD to directly load into installation media ?

Comment: get the Win10 ISO and do the upgrade: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557