# Using Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth to fix corrupt System Files

Tags: windows-10

I need help using Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth to fix corrupt system files. I tried sfc/scannow, and it said it found corrupt system files, but can't fix them. I then proceeded to look up this issue, and it told me to use the Dism command. Here is the error that I got:

```
Error: 0x800f081f
The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more Information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077
```

Keep in mind that I'm repairing my actual system, not an ISO.

Please help me!

Comment: look in CBS and DISM logs which files are missing.

Comment: Found this: 'Session: 30567853_2897710740 failed to perform store corruption detect and repair operation. [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]' in CBS.log

Comment: Actually I don't think that it has anything to do with missing files, it just can't find a mounted ISO in the default location. This is not what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to fix my system, not an ISO, so I don't know what could be happening.

Comment: Download the ISO, mount the ISO, and use the wim file contained on the ISO as the source.

Comment: share the CBS and DISM log folder and I'll look what fails

Comment: CBS file: https://mega.nz/#F!XkxmGZoY!QfAteDOvSMB7mKzKOXoAgA                               DISM file: https://mega.nz/#F!LgwmVDyS!3EejYCg-ZiROANwdg-AE7A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the logs, shows that 1 file is damaged:

`(p)    CSI Payload Corrupt         x86_microsoft-windows-w..ywmdmshellextension_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_5f441c558cd56176\audiodev.dll`

`10.0.14393.0` is the Anniversary update of Windows 10, so [get a clean ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), double click on the ISO to mount the ISO and run

`Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess`

*(where D: is your mounted Win10 1607 ISO)*

Now DISM can fetch the required `audiodev.dll` from the install.wim.