# Cannot update to Windows 10 on HP 15-f014wm

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to update to Windows 10 on my 15-f014wm laptop. I'm using the "Windows10Upgrader9194.exe" (which updated itself, so the presumably version number at the end may be wrong) thing to update, but after trying to update, it restarts, shows me a window saying that Windows 10 couldn't be installed, which had this message:

```
The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during BOOT operation
```

I have "Legacy Mode" turned off in the BIOS, if that means anything.

Here's my setuperr.log file:

```
2017-01-15 19:30:36, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2017-01-15 19:30:36, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(735): Result = 0x800705BB
2017-01-15 19:30:36, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(391): Result = 0x800705BB
2017-01-15 19:30:37, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(236): Result = 0x800705BB
2017-01-15 19:30:37, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(372): Result = 0x800705BB
2017-01-15 19:31:19, Error                        CallPidGenX: PidGenX function failed on this product key. (hr = 0x8a010001)
2017-01-15 19:31:19, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionProductKeyValidate::ReportDownlevelInstallChannel(2899): Result = 0x8A010001
2017-01-15 19:31:19, Error                 MOUPG  ProductKey: Failed to report Host OS channel to telemetry.
2017-01-15 19:31:25, Error                        CallPidGenX: PidGenX function failed on this product key. (hr = 0x8a010001)
2017-01-15 19:31:31, Error                        CallPidGenX: PidGenX function failed on this product key. (hr = 0x8a010001)
2017-01-15 19:45:19, Error                 CONX   Failed hashing for syswow64\drivers\vstor2-mntapi20-shared.sys, 0x80070003

2017-01-15 19:45:19, Error                 CONX   Failed hashing for [syswow64\drivers\vstor2-mntapi20-shared.sys] 0x80070003

2017-01-15 19:52:37, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::AssetUtils::GetProgramNameAndRegistryPathFromFile (724):   App should have registry path, swallowing error.[gle=0x8007139f]
2017-01-15 19:52:37, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::DataMigrationOutputter::PullAssetInfoOrDefaults (444):   Failed to get program name or arp registry path from application asset: [0x80004005].[gle=0x80004005]
2017-01-15 19:52:37, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::DataMigrationOutputter::DoOutput (213):   Failed to pull asset info for file: [0x80004005].[gle=0x80004005]
2017-01-15 19:55:41, Error                 SP     Using current time as Recovery Timestamp.
2017-01-15 19:58:36, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2017-01-15 20:01:56, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2017-01-15 20:01:58, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:01:58, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:01:58, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:05:53, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:05:53, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:05:53, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:06:14, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:06:17, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] Failed to get preferred homegroup with hr=0x80070490
2017-01-15 20:06:58, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: CBrgUnattend::CollectBridgeSettings failed: 0x1, 0
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: Cannot find log file "C:\WINDOWS\INF\setupapi.dev.log". Error = 0x00000002
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:17, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:07:25, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {D12A3141-A1FF-4DAD-BF67-1B664DE1CBD6}: WSLicensing: Failed to read machine binding, hr=0x80070002
2017-01-15 20:07:25, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {D12A3141-A1FF-4DAD-BF67-1B664DE1CBD6}: WSLicensing: Error reading Server Info hr=0x80070490
2017-01-15 20:07:26, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:26, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:26, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:07:26, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:26, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007e.[gle=0x0000007e]
2017-01-15 20:07:26, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Client-License-Platform-Service-Migration\ClipMigPlugin.dll, {6014E67F-2537-48F9-951D-D29D720523E1}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007e].
2017-01-15 20:07:49, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2017-01-15 20:07:49, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Download the current Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft, use that instead of the application your using, to update to Windows 10.

Comment: get the ISO from here: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557 and now try to use it to upgrade

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and got the same error.