# Windows 10 Version 1511 Wont Update to 1607 Error 0x800700005

Tags: windows-10-v1607

For several Months now my WIN-10 computer has not been able to update itself from **Version 1511 to version 1607**.  It makes the attempt each and every day, but fails with error code **0x800700005** and rolls back to version 1511. SFC and Registry Cleanup and rebuilds offer no solution. I am hoping someone has an answer, since this seems to be a fairly universal problem for some users.  Here are the details

HP PAVILION ELITE e9237 DESKTOP PC 
64 Bit, 8GB RAM  2TB DRIVE C:
**I Have Windows Version  10.0 PRO Build 10586**
I have W10 1511 build  10586.753 (It wont update)
I think I need W10 1607 build 14393.726     kb3216755 (for PRO?)
            or W10 1607 build 14393.729    kb4010672  (for PRO?)

```
=====================================================
**EVENT VIEWER ERROR LOGS
=====================================================
EVENT VIEWER Log Name:      System**
==================================================
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient
Date:          2/22/2017 12:34:12 AM
Event ID:      20
Task Category: **Windows Update Agent**
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Failure,Installation
User:          SYSTEM    Computer:      SCOTT-HP
Description:
Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070005: Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607.
Event Xml:

  
    
    20
    1
    2
    1
    13
    0x8000000000000028
    
    7455682
    
    
    System
    SCOTT-HP
    
  
  
    **0x80070005**
    Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607
    {C9FD5DC1-4180-41BB-9081-D009579BF32D}
    200
    {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}
  
=================================================
===============================================
**EVENT VIEWER Log Name:      Setup** 
===============================================
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WUSA
Date:          1/20/2017 10:25:43 PM
Event ID:      3
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SCOTT-HP\SCOTT    Computer:      SCOTT-HP
Description:
Windows update  could not be installed because of error **2149842967** "" (Command line: ""C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Users\SCOTT\Documents\windows10.0-kb3213986-x64_a1f5adacc28b56d7728c92e318d6596d9072aec4.msu" ")
Event Xml:

  
    
    3
    0
    2
    0
    0
    0x8000000000000000
    
    133
    
    
    Setup
    SCOTT-HP
    
  
  
    
    
    2149842967
    
    
    "C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Users\SCOTT\Documents\windows10.0-kb3213986-x64_a1f5adacc28b56d7728c92e318d6596d9072aec4.msu" 
  

=====================================================

==============================================================
**WINDOWS 10 ROLLBACK ERRORS UPON FAILURE**
=============================================================
**C:\windows10upgrade\getcurrentrollback.exe
2/10/2017 6:50 PM   Windows Error Reporting Fault bucket** , **type 0**
Event Name: WindowsUpdateFailure3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 10.0.10586.672
P2: 80070005
P3: C9FD5DC1-4180-41BB-9081-D009579BF32D
P4: Install
P5: 200
P6: 0
P7: 0
P8: UpdateOrchestrator
P9: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}
P10: 0

Attached files:

These files may be available here:


Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: cfc06bd1-efc1-11e6-be58-00133b0ee5bf
Report Status: 262144
Hashed bucket:

**2/10/2017 7:19 PM Windows Error Reporting Fault bucket 127789396559**, **type 5**
Event Name: WindowsUpdateFailure3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 10.0.10586.672
P2: 80070005
P3: C9FD5DC1-4180-41BB-9081-D009579BF32D
P4: Install
P5: 200
P6: 0
P7: 0
P8: UpdateOrchestrator
P9: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}
P10: 0

Attached files:
C:\Windows\Temp\WER3585.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\****NonCritical**_10.0.10586.672**_36b5ab3916eca4e8a6433c12d673f663322fd_00000000_11047d1f

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: cfc06bd1-efc1-11e6-be58-00133b0ee5bf
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 025e1a96e512a1001f2672a5458bc5fa
```

Comment: Download current 1607 ISO, mount it, launch the installer.

Comment: here is the way to get ISO: http://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557 if upgrade still fails, share the folder **C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther** as zip on OneDrive. I'll ask my Microsoft contacts for help.

Comment: have you tried the upgrade via mounted ISO? does it also fail? if yes, have you created the feedback? Can you please post the link here?

Comment: @Scott any update on the issue?