# How do I get Win10 back on my computer after System restore

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, restore

I did a full factory restore on my computer and now that it is back set up it has reverted back to Windows 8(the OS that it was shipped with) 
I had Windows 10 before the system restore, and am hoping that I can get it back somehow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: any update on your issue? Have you tried the ISO from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

When you activated Windows 10 during the free upgrade, Microsoft stores the hash of your PC components on their activation servers and when you reinstall Windows 10 on the same hardware, skip the product key during setup and Windows will detect that Windows 10 was used on the HW before and activates it again.

So get the [1607 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO by doing a double click on the ISO, run setup.exe to upgrade and skip the key to get Windows 10 activated again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have to run the Windows 10 upgrade process again. I don't know whether you have a retail copy of Windows 10 with which to do this--if you do, I guess you'll just put in the installation media and upgrade from there--but if don't have this but you use assistive technologies, Microsoft [offers a free upgrade](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade?tduid=(14c348e893a91089cb2980533c6ee123)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-0FBZfNm6YPFXNhiu3o52rA)()) to their latest OS.

Answer (score -1):

The free upgrade to Windows 10 has expired (other than for people who need 'assistive technologies').

If you contact Microsoft, they're usually pretty helpful in helping sort out licencing issues like this. They should let you reinstall and help you get Win 10 licenced again.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/