# Windows license

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, license

I want to buy a laptop that it comes with windows 10 home in chinese and it has a license.

In the product page it says that if I change to english language there will still be some words in chinese, mainly in the windows start menu.

I would like to know, if I format the chinese windows and install a new english windows from a usb will this OS have a valid license?

Comment: The license is not bound to a Langauge. get an english 1703 (build 15063, which will be released on april 11th) ISO and install windows 10 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows license is not bound to special language unless you use a special edition for China which only supports Chinese, but this edition won't allow you to setup other languages like you did.

So get an official Windows 10 [1607](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)/[1703 (this is the version for the Creators update which will be released starting on April 11th 2017)](http://winaero.com/blog/official-iso-images-windows-10-build-15063-released-slow-ring/) ISO and reinstall Windows 10 with an English ISO (English international = en-GB and English US is English ISO for United States, keep that in mind). Make sure you look which Edition you use (Home/Pro) so that Windows can use the OEm key from the UEFI to activate the Windows again.

Now you have a fully translated fresh Windows 10.

Comment: The windows of the notebook is windows 10 home single language (and that language is chinese). This means that a fresh install of windows in another language won't be activated?

Comment: no, single language means you can't install any additional languages. But single language is available as english(international), Portuguese (brazil): https://tb.rg-adguard.net/

Answer (score 2):

Be sure of install the same version of Windows that you previously had. If the installer asks for a license key, press skip (usually it asks for a license two times). 
After you connect your device to Internet, a license should be applied automatically.