# 'Windows 10 installation file is corrupted' message while updating windows in brand new laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Just 10 hours using my new Asus Zenbook 3 and I wanted to update windows 10 as I was suggested for blurred text problem  but I got this error code **0x8007000d**. Windows is preinstalled so I don't have neither the key product nor a installation disc.

What should I do?

Comment: Contact Asus...

Comment: Create an installation disk.  Windows 10 doesn't require you to enter an installation key, its **automatically** detected.  [Windows 10 Iso](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-anniversary-update-build-14393)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you try to update your Windows 10 to Windows 10 version 1703 got the error code?
If it is available to boot your device, we could try the following steps to fix the issue.
1. Check error codes recorded in the Event Viewer(Windows Logs\Applications, Setup, System).
2. Run built-in windows troubleshooting tool:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\ System and Security\Fix problems with Windows Update\Advanced\Run as administrator
3. Run the command “sfc /scannow” with administrator right to check the health of system files. 
4. Perform a Clean Boot following the document and manually update again.

If the issue persists, download a Windows 10 ISO from the link below then choose “Upgrade” install.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Best regards,
Joy.