# Replacing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint

So I got a used laptop (Dell Latitude 16GB RAM, 255GB SSD) and it came with Windows 10. I activated Windows with the product key that came with my laptop.

I immediately replaced Windows with Linux Mint Cinnamon x64. I'm happy with it, but I am now realizing I really need Windows to play any of the games I did before. So I now want to dual boot Windows 10. My question involves what happens once I make my bootable disc/drive.

Will I be able to use the same product key I activated Windows with originally to activate it for the dual boot install, or will I have to purchase a new one or something? If so I can reuse the key, is the process the same as installing any other new OS?

Comment: Your same key should work, it may even be automatically recognized as already registered, since this is an Dell OEM key it keys off a code in the UEFI/BIOS... this is not a big issue, people do it all the time and there is no reason you should have to buy another key.

Comment: Yes, you can reuse the key. You will also need to use a tool such as [woeusb](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) to create the install usb, because directly writing the image does not work.

Comment: That was my big concern, would Windows dissuade people from downloading other OS's by requiring a new product key every time you reinstall Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get a clean ISO of the Windows 10 Anniversary update (Build 14393) or Creators Update (Build 15063)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-anniversary-update-build-14393-o)

Comment: You didn't have to activate your installation, it already was activated because it's an OEM license.  Furthermore Microsoft has never required you to purchase another license to reinstall Windows on OEM hardware. Additionally Windows 10 automatically activates on hardware its previously been activated on.

Answer (score 1):

If you had Windows 10 activated previously on the laptop you need not re-enter they key.  When prompted during installation click on "I don't have a product key" and it will automatically activate after installation is complete and you connect to the internet.

If you saved the key (by using a keyfinder to retrieve it) before installing Mint you could re-enter it but there is no need.

In either case if prompted you must install the same version (Home or Pro) that you had before.  If you have your OEM key embedded in your firmware you'll not be asked.