# Windows 10 USB installation stuck at 'Copying Windows files (0%)'

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-installation

After formatting the SSD in my laptop, I am trying to install Windows 10 on it using a USB created from the Windows Media Creation Tool (I have tried multiple USBs). When I do this, the process does not get farther than 'Copying Windows files (0%)'.

I have formatted it, cleaned it, and checked it for write protection through the Windows commandprompt but it still does not proceed. I know ubuntu can be installed on it, but not Win 10.

Comment: What build of Windows 10, are you trying to install, hopefully you are installing 1703

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I am installing 1703

Comment: get a [clean ISO from MS](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557) and use tools like rufus to create a bootabe USB drive

Answer (score 0):

Try booting off a Windows DVD if your system has a DVD R/W available. It should work like a charm. Let me know about any troubles throug comments.

Answer (score 0):

Right, this solution may sound really far-fetched, but bear with me as this worked for me.

1. Grab the tool Rufus and an Ubuntu ISO, both are available online.
2. Use Rufus to burn the ISO to a USB. Choose the FAT32 option and if your partition table is MBR, choose the option that has 'BIOS' in it else choose one of the UEFI options.
3. When it is done, boot from the Ubuntu USB. When asked, select Try Ubuntu.
4. Once you see a desktop, press CTRL ALT T to load the terminal. Keep this open in the background.
5. Search for a program called Disks, open it and navigate to your SSD. Make a note of its path, eg /Dev/*D*
6. Going back to the terminal window you should have open, type in the following commands, where [path] is the path of your SSD, so something like /Dev/*d*:

   `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass passkey [path]`

   `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase passkey [path]`

   `sudo hdparm -I [path]`
7. At the end of the last command, you should see some lines of text. Look for the line that says 'not frozen'. That means it has been done correctly. If it says 'frozen', this fix probably won't work for you.
8. Turn your computer off, and boot to your Windows 10 USB.
9. Go through the options, then press 'Custom Install'. Delete all partitions shown, highlight the unallocated space then press Next. The installation should go perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Also just try waiting a long time on older machines. The copying files percentage may just stay on 0% for the entire copy process, but then continues with installation as normal when finished copying.

Comment: Why downvoted? This is exactly what occurred for me. I found this question while my install was stuck on 0%