# Bootable usb not working in legacy mode

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bootable-media, legacy

I am installing windows 8.1 on my laptop . The problem is when I run in legacy mode my bootable usb not load . I mean a screen appears like command prompt . (With a blinker like this )

```
_
```

I stuck there forever
But when I boot in uefi mode my usb load but I don want to install window on gpt partiton because I have some important data on my drives ( large data )

What I can do
Please it will be best If I can install window on legacy mode rather than uefi
I will try to upload a pic tomarow
Any help will be appreciated
Have a good day :)

Comment: Windows 8.1 (when I had it a few years back) needed UEFI and changed the BIOS on my laptop. If you need Windows 8.1 (or Windows 10) you will need to back up everything and allow Windows to install.

Comment: hi, the following link might be helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/1246255/install-windows-10-in-legacy-boot-mode