# Windows 10 creators update failing to black screen on restart

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 keeps forcing me to update with the creators update, I've done this process about 10 times with no success.

I allow it to update, on the restart the screen stays black for over an hour before I power off and back on, it then goes to 'restoring your previous version of windows'. Then within a week it prompts me to update again. I cannot ping the pc during a black screen.

I've looked through the WindowsUpdate.log from the Get-WindowsUpdateLog powershell command and don't see anything strange... It is 1.5mb, so I can't paste it here.

This is the portion of the shutdown and 35 minutes of black screen:

```
2017/09/02 11:35:31.0170533 268   1620  Agent           Sending shutdown notification to client
2017/09/02 11:35:31.0234150 268   1620  Agent           Sending shutdown notification to client
2017/09/02 11:35:31.0247464 268   1620  Agent           Sending shutdown notification to client
2017/09/02 11:35:31.0250752 268   1620  Agent           Sending shutdown notification to client
2017/09/02 11:35:31.1020870 268   1620  Shared          * END * Service exit Exit code = 0x240001
2017/09/02 12:10:19.3822448 932   2680  Shared          * START * Service startup
2017/09/02 12:10:19.4001605 932   2680  Agent           WU client version 10.0.14393.1532
2017/09/02 12:10:19.4004579 932   2680  Agent           SleepStudyTracker: Machine is non-AOAC. Sleep study tracker disabled.
2017/09/02 12:10:19.4005326 932   2680  Agent           Base directory: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution
2017/09/02 12:10:19.4023985 932   2680  Agent           Datastore directory: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb
2017/09/02 12:10:19.5030921 932   2680  DataStore       DS: Database will be reset next time it starts up due to 0x80248006
2017/09/02 12:10:19.5030974 932   2680  DataStore       Datastore version is incorrect. Expected 4.1-4.1, but got 4.0.
2017/09/02 12:10:19.5668020 932   2680  DataStore       Forcing re-creation of data store
2017/09/02 12:10:20.0242834 932   2680  DataStore       Service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 added
2017/09/02 12:10:20.0402268 932   2680  DataStore       Service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 added
```

Comment: stop WU service and delete all folders inside C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution. now try windows update again. if this fails, get an [1703 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO, run setup.exe and upgrade

Comment: Not sure if that fixed it, but it did finally update. However, now the system is extremely unstable... Randomly blue screens with irql_not_less_or_equal and netio.sys errors, typically a few minutes after signing in. This was a kodi pc, so I've decided to just go with openelec, which runs fine.

Comment: [analyze the dumps with winbbg.exe](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)