# Can Windows reset save my computer?

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware, reset, microsoft-edge

I've gone through some kind of virus and malware apocalypse after downloading some stuff, and antiviruse programs fail to clean everything. What is worse, after deleting what seemed to me as some malware remnants, Microsoft Edge stopped working.

So I thought that the only way to recover my PC is a full Windows reset, but I don't have an installation disc nor restore point. I still can reset my PC, but I'm not sure if Edge will work again. I just don't want to end up with a clean computer without any access to the internet.

Does anyone know if resetting my PC will help?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Appleoddity windows 10

Comment: [Just download the current 1703 Windows 10 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-anniversary-update-build-14393-o)

Comment: I would run [Microsoft Security Essentials for windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5201). Generally takes car of most issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers the MediaCreationTool free of charge.  Get an **empty** 8gb or larger USB stick.  Use the tool to convert it into an installation media.

Download your network drivers and save them on the USB stick.

1. Backup your important file to USB external hard drive.
2. Boot from USB stick
3. Format, and re-install windows
4. Re-apply your network driver.
5. Use web browser to download everything else.

http://devid.info/  will help

Comment: Thanks, but what does the re-applying the network driver mean?

Comment: @Uzzernaim it depends on your network driver.  Some come as EXE files you can just run, and an installer installs them. Some come as a ZIP file you open up, and then have to go into the device manager, right click the NIC and select update driver.  Then point the dialog box at the unzipped version of the driver.