# Windows 10 installer don't detect NVMe drive

Tags: boot, drivers, multi-boot, windows-installation, windows-installer

I have 2 drives:

- disk1 (SATA SSD, with Ubuntu 16.04)

  - partition1 (sda1: flag /boot)
  - partition2 (sda2: flag /home, encrypted by LUKS)
- disk2 (NVMe SSD)

So, the goal is to install Windows 10 on disk2 and **boot it from GRUB** (which is on sda1).

What is the problem ?

In disk-choose step, disk2 is missing.
However **Ubuntu 14.04 installer "see" this disk**, so I assume **that is software issue**, rather than my hardware.

What I tried to solve this problem ?

- loaded Samsung NVMe drivers from [this thread](http://www.win-raid.com/t29f25-Recommended-AHCI-RAID-and-NVMe-Drivers.html)
- patched Windows image using DISM tool by adding 2 updates. I followed
  [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2990941/update-to-add-native-driver-support-in-nvm-express-in-windows-7-and-wi)
- tried to run Windows 10 installed on USB stick to install it

All of them failed.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you need to add the driver to the boot.wim not install.wim. have you done this?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, I linked guide for this.

Comment: which win10 build do you use?

Comment: @magicandre1981 mainly i tried intsall Windows 10 Professional N but somtimes I tried with Windows 10 Professional (N version doesn't include Windows Media Player, thats all difference)

Comment: this is the edition/SKU. I mean the version/build (v1507/Build10240 or v1511/Build 10586 or v1607/Build 14393 or v1703/Build 15063 or the newest v1709/Build 16299? Try the newest version if possible. it always has best HW support.

Comment: I've posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557) how to get the Windows 10 ISOs. Try here the newest 1709 ISO

Comment: @magicandre1981 I used the ISO downloaded yesterday from micosoft website, so i assume it's pretty new.

Answer (score -1):

So. The solution is:

> When arrive at the custom advanced screen during setup, press Shift +
>   F10
>
> type the following commands
>
> DISKPART
>
> Hit Enter
>
> list volume
>
> Next you will select the volume where you would like to install
>   Windows 10   Type: select disk #
>
> # represents the number the volume
>
> Type: clean
>
> convert mbr
>
> create partition primary
>
> active
>
> format quick fs=ntfs
>
> exit
>
> exit

And next:

> Select the drive, click Delete
>
> This will convert it to unallocated
>
> Select it, click New
>
> It should create additional partitions (system reserved and primary)
>
> Select the primary drive then click Next

Comment: looks like the drive was UEFI/GPT formatting but you created a MBR stlyle uSB drive