# After Windows 1709 update (Fall Creators Update), there are "corrupt files not fixed" when running sfc /scannow

Tags: windows-10-v1709

I have run sfc /scannow periodically ever since getting this laptop in March, and it never comes up with any errors. However, after the latest 1709 update (Fall Creators Edition) of Windows installed, I have been getting the message "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them..." I was also having problems with the mouse and keyboard being completely unresponsive at times (I discovered that closing the lid and putting it to sleep, and then opening the lid again and waking it up made the mouse and keyboard return to normal), and also a blue screen - both problems that I had not had before the 1709 update.

I decided to re-install Windows, but I was concerned about losing some programs that came with the computer that weren't Windows programs, and therefore would be lost with a Windows re-installation (like the program that controls the backlight colors, which is nice). So I did a "Reset this PC" instead, but after doing so, I found that the "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them..." error message was still there upon running sfc /scannow.

I've tried a different method - using the Media Creation Tool to update, as opposed to installing the update through Windows Update (which is what resulted in all the problems starting in the first place), but the same error appears when running sfc /scannow.

I tried a different method, going back to a back-up I made using AOMEI Backupper a few months ago (July), which was still under the 1703 update. After reverting to that disk backup, I then did the "Reset" again and then ran sfc /scannow - and it showed that no errors were found. However, I realized that the "Reset" resulted in a "clean" version of the 1703 update - not the 1709 update - being installed. So then I tried using the Windows10Upgrade9252.exe that I downloaded from the Microsoft website which installs the 1709 update itself, instead of using Windows Update or the Media Creation Tool (which had both resulted in the sfc /scannow error message). Again, after the 1709 update finished installing, the same error message appeared in sfc /scannow.

I've tried running "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth", "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth", and "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" - and then running sfc /scannow again, but it's still the same error message. I've tried running sfc /scannow in Safe Mode, but it's the same error message.

I see that others have also had problems after the 1709 update installed on their computers, but I don't think I've found any solution that applies to my particular problem. I don't know if this sfc /scannow error message is happening for everyone who installs the 1709 update, or if it's just me. Perhaps it's an issue with a new Windows build that they will fix eventually?

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this problem - or if anyone can tell me whether this is "normal" to have this error message - I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you all.

Comment: So which files are corrupt.  Check the log.  If you did a Reset then your programs had to be reinstalled but it also would mean that Windows was reinstalled.

Comment: I looked through the CBS.log file, but it's hard to make anything of it. Yes, I assumed Windows would be reinstalled, so it seems like there's something inherently corrupt in the 1709 update for me (but not necessarily for everyone else?)

Comment: Oh, I think I see what the problem is. I looked through the CBS.log file again and did a search for "corrupt" and found that they're all in the C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\zh-tw\ and C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-hk\zh-hk\ folders. Those must be associated with the "secondary keyboard layout" that they asked me if I wanted to add, during the 1709 installation (I chose "Traditional Chinese-Taiwan"). Let me try to reset it again without choosing any secondary keyboard layout (I don't really need it, I only chose one because they asked me to) and see if the sfc /scannow errors are no longer there. Thanks.

Comment: Just uninstall the keyboard layout in question.  Your system doesn’t need to be Reset again

Comment: It's still showing the corrupt files in the same folders - after uninstalling the secondary keyboard layout, restarting the computer, and running sfc /scannow again. I think I'll go ahead and reset it.

Comment: You have tried mounting the .wim from a 1709 ISO and running DISM against it as a source?

Comment: look in CBS.log which files are are corrupted

Comment: It's strange, I've reset it (multiple times, using various methods) without adding the secondary keyboard layout, but it's still giving the same message after running sfc /scannow, and it's still showing the same corrupt files in those same folders (e.g., "00000cae [SR] Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\zh-tw\ChtAP.sdc from store").

Comment: I saw the suggestion to run "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:repairSource\install.wim" but I don't know how to get the "install.wim" file. When I run MediaCreationTool, it gives me a "Windows.iso" file, so I put the location of that file for the "Source" - perhaps that's doing it wrong.

Comment: I found a "boot.wim" file, but not a "install.wim" file.

Comment: the install.wim is only in the official ISOs not the self generated one from MediaCreationTool. [I posted a way to get real ISOs](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Is there a difference between the official ISO and the one generated by MediaCreationTool?

Comment: I ran the DISM tool with the install.wim file as the source, then ran sfc /scannow again - but it still gives the same "found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them" message. The CBS.log file still shows the same folders containing corrupt files (for example, "Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-hk\zh-hk\ChtAP.sdc from store" and "Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\zh-tw\ChtAP.sdc from store").

Comment: the MediaCreationTool generates ISos with a Install.esd, not a WIM. Open cmd.exe as admin in CBS folder and run this: **findstr /c:"[SR]" CBS.log >sfcdetails.txt** now look which files can't be repaired.  "Repairing corrupted file from store" means it was fixed.

Comment: I see... thanks for the explanation. After doing some more research, it seems that this is an issue that some (but not all) have after installing new builds. Someone said that he/she had this issue after installing the 16299.19 build but it went away after the 16299.64 build, so I guess I'll just have to wait for the next build. I ran the command prompt line you gave, and it doesn't say that any files can't be repaired. All it shows are eight instances of "Repairing corrupt file...from store." Here's the sfcdetails.txt file if you want to see for yourself: http://www.filedropper.com/sfcdetails

Comment: so maybe this is a bug. ignore it and only run DISM, sfc is no longer recommend.

Comment: Yes, I hope so. Thanks for your help, magicandre1981 (and Ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

That's a stupid bug.

There is neither C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-hk\zh-hk\ nor C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\zh-tw\ directories.  Only C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-hk\ and C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\ exist.

The workaround would be to create the directories.  Copy the the two files ChtAP.sdc and chtzhy.spd from C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-hk\ to C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-hk\zh-hk\ and from C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\ to C:\WINDOWS\System32\zh-tw\zh-tw\ respectively to the new directories.

Sfc should now show no corrupt files.