# Windows Defender reports error 0x800b0100

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

On startup, Windows 10 pops up the following alert:

> An error has occurred in the program during initialization. If this problem continues, please contact your system administrator.
>
> Error code: 0x800b0100

Windows is up to date and I've done my research, but `sfc /scannow` and `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` didn't fix the problem - the former just reported that there were corrupted files, not how to restore them (the resulting `CBS.log` is several megabytes in size and not very helpful either).

The same error pops up whenever I try to access Windows Defender via the start menu - however, both `services.msc` and the Windows Defender section within Windows Settings report that the respective services are active.

a) Can I safely assume that the machine is properly protected?

b) How can I get rid of this annoying dialog?

I'd very much appreciate any help.

Comment: run this command to fix the issue: **dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth**

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't make a difference; afterwards, the error pops up just as before and `sfc /scannow` still reports corrupted files. (Sorry for the late response; this isn't my machine, I only have access to it on weekends.)

Comment: look in CBS.log which files can't be repaired

Comment: That log is several megabytes in size, ~40k lines - anything I could search for? (Terms like "corruption" don't yield much useful information, or perhaps it's just too cryptic for me to understand.)

Comment: open cmd.exe as admin in C:\Windows\Logs\CBS and run **findstr /c:"[SR]" CBS.log > sfcdetails.txt** now open sfcdetails.txt and look which files can't be restored

Comment: I'm afraid that just gives me a bunch of repetitive messages: "Verifying 1 components", "Beginning Verify and Repair transaction" and "Verify complete" (with prefixes like "CSI 00000006 [SR]"), no file names or anything more detailed.

Comment: share the txt file (onedrive share link)

Comment: Thanks for the offer, here's the latest `CBS.log`: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26103610/

Comment: different link please (onedrive), this one doesnÄt allow downloading the file. also only share the sfcdetails.txt

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know downloading required an account on pastebin.ubuntu,com (I don't have a OneDrive account). This should do it: https://filebin.ca/3jX08xFa2G4l/CBS.log and 
https://filebin.ca/3jX1JOC89WJe/sfcdetails.txt

Comment: hm, the logs show that update KB4017100 is corrupted. I see that you still run the old 1607, so [get the 1709 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), run setup.exe and keep apps/settings to upgrade to last version.

Comment: Sorry for the late response: I never did manage to fix this (I'd tried a _lot_ of things), eventually giving up and letting Microsoft support dial into the machine - they fixed it with what seemed like registry mangling.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended you to fix this problem, instead of ignoring it. Try below suggestions.

Re-start system in Clean Boot - **Perform a clean startup to determine whether background programs are interfering with your game or program:**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/331796/perform-a-clean-startup-to-determine-whether-background-programs-are-i

**>the former just reported that there were corrupted files**

If both SFC and DISM.EXE reports error about system files. If there is system backup available, just restore system back to previous working state.

Besides, you can try - **How to: Perform a Repair Upgrade Using the Windows 10 ISO file  Important thread**:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, Clean Boot doesn't make a difference; running the same commands again, the error pops up just as before and `sfc /scannow` still reports corrupted files.

There's no system backup I could restore either, so I'll try the Repair Upgrade and will report back.

(Sorry for the late response; this isn't my machine, I only have access to it on weekends.)