# windows 10 media creation tool error code: 0x80072F76 - 0X20017

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting

I get this problem while running [windows 10 media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10), and I get the following error code **0x80072F76 - 0X20017** exactly as the below image:

I have tried to chat with Microsoft support agent but no one can connect with me

[image]

Comment: See this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-media-creation-tool-error-0x80072f76/1c93a0f8-0e86-49e8-bf24-44d99da85c71?auth=1).

Comment: [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool Error 0x80072f76 - 0x20017](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/media-creation-tool-error-0x80072f76-20017/). Alternately, try the DNS server `9.9.9.9` -- works for some users

Comment: 0x80072F76 = ERROR_WINHTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND so check your Internet connection. But it is better to [get a clean ISO from Microsoft](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)

Comment: thank you, after download how can i install it on my usb as media?

Comment: you can use [Rufus to create a bootable USb drive from the ISO](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)