# Why does Ubuntu on Windows crash on startup?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, windows-10-preview, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17074 for PC. The Windows Subsystem for Linux is enabled and I've installed Ubuntu on Windows from the Windows Store.

Whenever I try to launch Ubuntu, it fails with the following error message:

"The data area passed to a system call is too small."

[image]

I've tried uninstalling/installing the app (via Apps & features) and disabling/enabling the Linux Subsystem (via Turn Windows features on or off), but still get the same error.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: Windows version]

[image: Error message]

[image: Install Ubuntu]

[image: Uninstall Ubuntu]

Comment: I haven't seen this, but I did remove WSL before installing Ubuntu on Windows. I don't know if there is a conflict between the two versions, but I suggest you remove both before installing Ubuntu again.

Comment: 17074 Isn’t 1709 that’s a Insidsr Preview build for RS4 which would be more like what will become 1803.

Comment: "I've tried uninstalling/installing the app and disabling/enabling the Linux Subsystem, but still get the same error." - This doesn't reset the environment. How did you uninstall the application exactly?  Edit your question.

Comment: In this case the output of `WinVer` isn't correct.  [10.0.17074 · VERSION 1803 · REDSTONE 4](https://changewindows.org/build/redstone4/17074/pc#1002).  1709 has a build of 16299 any build higher than that is RS4.  Anyways this particular error has happened to various programs and isn't specifically linked to anything to do with WSL.

Comment: Try running `wslconfig /unregister Ubuntu` in an elevated PowerShell prompt.  However, worth pointing out, the directory stated in the error, does not appear to be correct. *This might have to do with the fact you are on a Slow Insider Preview channel.*

Comment: Running 'wslconfig /unregister Ubuntu' gives 'There is no distribution with the supplied name'. Running 'wslconfig /l' gives 'Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions'. I've tried openSUSE Leap 42 and it also gives a 'data area too small' error.

Comment: If Ubuntu isn't supported on Slow Insider Preview then that's fine, but presumably this should be documented somewhere? If it's a bug, is it a bug in Windows or the app? If I've got a borked Windows installation then it's not worth reinstalling just to get this app running.

Comment: update to [Build 17083](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/01/24/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17083-for-pc/) and look wha happens. Insider Version tend to have more issues compared to stable Versions.

Comment: I would guess that the Ubuntu version you got from the Store cannot work on the Insider Preview. You use Insider Preview at your own risk - this version is meant for developers to test the compatibility of their software to the upcoming version of Windows, not for serious work.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you use an Insider Preview Build 17074 of the next Feature Update:

[image]

In this preview Version, Microsoft makes a lot of changes and bugs are expected. So try lastest Windows 10 Insider Preview (as of writing this is [Build 17083](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/01/24/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17083-for-pc/)) and look if the issue is fixed. If not, report the issue to Microsoft via [Feedback Hub App](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app).

**Backup all data** and go to the stable Windows 10 Fall Creators Update v1709 (Build 16299) by doing a clean install [via 1709 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557). Now install the Linux Subsystem again and use Ubuntu. This should be stable.

Comment: This error logged in GitHub. You can't solve that by clean installing. [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2808).

Comment: @biswapriyo Thanks for the link, change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @LukeGirvin That is not an answer. And I don't know about that problem so much. If I know details I'll definitely do that.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug which occurs when SQL Server is running with the filestream feature enabled, as described in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/centennial-appsdesktop-bridge-sql-server-and-error-the-data-area-passed-to-a-system-call-is-too-small/):

> Simply speaking, this issue occurs due to due to miscommunication between two filter drivers, namely WCNFS (the desktop bridge) and RsFxXXXX.sys driver (filestream system driver). RsFx system driver doesn't honor flags being passed by WCNFS driver appropriately, which causes startup failure of any Centennial application with the aforementioned error.

Stopping the SQL Server service let me run Ubuntu.