# Downloading Microsoft Windows ISOs

Tags: windows, operating-systems, iso-image, windows-installation

I have a valid product key for Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 Pro, however since downloading the ISOs from their original providers, the links are now invalid (they were Microsoft links) and I don't have the ISOs.

How can I get the ISO files legally?

Thanks.

Comment: There is an existing question on how to download Windows 10.  Windows Server 2012 can be downloaded from the volume license center website, same location, as you originally downloaded it from (but not the same link as those expire)

Comment: @Ramhound This was not a volume license and is not linked to a business account. The licenses were purchased from eBay

Comment: Windows Server is only licensed through a volume license.

Comment: get the [Windows 10 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own ISO for Windows 10 with the Microsoft tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/software-download/windows10)

For Windows Server [here](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2) is all of the Server ISO

---

**Note:** Those are eval version you will need to enter the settings and enter your product key to activate your Windows.