# Official downloads for Windows 10 N?

Tags: windows-10, download, iso-image

I know from experience that using a product key for an N version of Windows with a non-N version installation will fail.

Earlier I could just select the N edition in Microsoft's web form for downloading ISOs, but now when [trying to download Windows 10 N](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) all I'm offered is a media creation tool. As expected the tool was not a good replacement for the web form, and did not offer me any N versions.

- Why are no N versions offered? Have they been discontinued or something?
- Are they officially available somewhere else?

**Update:** I'm currently on Windows.

**Update 2:** None of the answers in the proposed duplicate solve the problem.

- 3rd party download link generator: "File is not available for download" on every try.
- Media creation tool: Doesn't work -- that's why I'm here.
- Change user agent in Firefox: Only offers me Windows 10 Fall Creator's Update. No N versions.
- HeiDoc Windows ISO downloader: **Update 3: *Initially*** abysmal transfer rates. They seem to increase to acceptable speeds after a while.

*File not available*
[image: File not available]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get a clean ISO of the Windows 10 AU (Build 14393), Creators Update (Build 15063) or FCU (Build 16299.15)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-au-build-14393-creators-update).  Before you make the conclusion, that this isn't duplicate, I encourage you read the duplicate and verify that is the case.

Comment: "Have they been discontinued or something?" - No; "Are they officially available somewhere else?" - Windows 10 N is indeed supported.  The linked you provide requires you to provide it a non-Windows browser agent to be used.  "Why are no N versions offered?" - I was able to select Windows 10 N Home/Professional without an issue

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. To clarify, were you able to select it in the media creation tool?

Comment: I thought you wanted to download the ISO, hence the reason you wanted to s to provide an alternative, to the Media Creation Tool?

Comment: @Ramhound If you have an alternative method while working in Windows, feel free to write an answer describing it!

Comment: The answer already exists.  Read all of the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I am currently working my way through them. If the answer turns up (not yet) I will update this question.

Comment: All of the answers will work. You should use Andre's answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, no, neither Andre's nor Codelt's (obviously) answers work. Biswapriyo's might stand a chance, as you've pointed out.

Comment: @Ramhound See updated question. Further suggestions welcomed.

Comment: I have personally verified all those methods.  Andre's suggestion while an external link, generates a link, directly from Microsoft.  While CodeIt's answer suggestion is to use the Media Creation Tool.  Give me a small amount of time to determine if a new answer should be submitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74258/discussion-between-ramhound-and-sirap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Microsoft support I was assured that

> Actually, once you boot the device with the Installation media [...]
>   you will see the Pro , Home a, N and KN editions. If and only if you
>   boot the device with an installation media.

The problem here was that the Media Creation Tool didn't tell you that all those variants were included in the edition that it simply calls "Windows 10", in combination with the fact that e.g. Windows 7 had different and incompatible images depending on whether your license key was N or not.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities are [listed here](https://superuser.com/q/1108085/36197), but the only answer from there that worked for me was [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1249729/36197), which unfortunately requires me to [download and run an unknown 3rd party .exe](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool?showall=&limitstart=), which pretty much openly asks me if it could mine cryptocurrency ("use resources") in the background. Needless to say that didn't make me more comfortable, but at least it actually offered the N versions for download.

The transfer speeds pick up after some time.

Comment: MSDN subscription.

Comment: Avent that does not offer me 1803's N edition... The media pack is offered, the N edition not...