# Windows 10 upgrade on dual Boot with Linux

Tags: multi-boot, grub2, ubuntu-16.04, windows-10-v1709

I have a dual boot laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 - with the following partitions :

```
Disk 1 - 128GB SSD : 
        160Mb EFI System boot partition
        128Mb - msftres (no idea)
        60GB - Windows 10 (C:\ - 23GB free)
        1 MB - unused
        1.5GB - ext3 - /boot
        20GB - ext3 - /
        20GB - linux-swap
        18GB - ntfs - shared game assets
        500Mb - ntfs - windows recovery - 200Mb free

Disk 2 - 2 TB
     128Mb - msftres
     1TB - ntfs - (D:\)
     900Mb - ext3 - (/home)
```

I have grub installed which allows me to boot whichever I wish.

From the Middle of March I have been prompted on windows to install a new version (Windows 10 is version 1607 currently).

**Update attempt 1 to n: Using Windows Update Assistance**

I tried downloading as prompted, which downloaded ok, the machine restarted - I chose Windows from the grub menu; it started installing - reached 25% and restarted again. Chose windows again from grub menu - windows restored previous version - no update.

I tried the Windows update troubleshooter - it found and 'fixed issues'; tried the update assistance again - same result. Ran the trouble shoot again, same issues found and fixed; tried again as above - same result - rinse and repeat every few days.

**Update attempt 2: Using Windows Media Creation Tool**

Using the tool, I burnt and verified a DVD - and booted my machine from that DVD; the DVD software could not even detect Windows on my machine despite it being fully authorized and licensed.

After this failed attempt - booting into windows gives this error :

[image: Windows Error - post DVD update attempt]

Needless to say this error code don't seem to exist on Microsoft's web sites.
- it is odd that this error is generated when the DVD claimed it couldn't even find a Windows version - but clearly it found something in order to trigger this error.

Running the Update Trouble shooter - again it claims to finds the same set of errors as it did previously - suggesting that the Trouble shooter is mostly pointless.

**Where Next ?**

So the big Question - How on Earth do i get windows to install this windows update ? [previously windows updates have always worked (even when they required a reboot), but this one just fails].

**Additional Info**

- looking at the Windows Event Log - there is no log message of any of the attempted upgrades, or any error message from any of the failures and windows re-versions.
- The machine uses UEFI - if that matters
- Laptop has 32GB RAM

Comment: For Windows updates from ISO, I've had better results with a USB device made with Media Creation tool than with a DVD, since DVD drivers were not available from UEFI... though if you could start booting from DVD, that is not likely the issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik *not likely the issue*... It depends. If the UEFI settings allow for Legacy/CSM (typically UEFI+Legacy instead of UEFI Only) then all bets are off, either a DVD or a USB can end up being booted in Legacy mode in which case it won't detect the installed OS.

Comment: I should have said - my laptop is fully capable of booting from the DVD.

Comment: remove GRUB, update Windows 10, reinstall GRUB. Windows doesn't like other bootloaders.

Comment: @magicandre1981that is despite the promise by Microsoft that they were going to play nice with other boot loaders ?
Given that the Troubleshooter app comes up with the same issues over and over again - I am not sure that it is the boot loader that is the problem ..

Comment: Microsoft never promised this. I also had to delete the android x86 boot entry to update to 1709. I reported it to Microsoft, so try the [1803 upgrade](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/04/30/how-to-get-the-windows-10-april-2018-update/) maybe they fixed it here.

Comment: I have no way of selecting which upgrade I get - in fact I don't even know which one is failing - failed upgrades aren't reported or logged in anyway - yet another microsft commitment to qualifty .... :-(

Comment: you get the forced 1709 upgrade. Delete the hidden **$WINDOWS.~BT** from C:\, [get the 1803 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount the ISO and run setup.exe, select upgrade/keep everything

Comment: have you tried the 1803 update? does it also fail? if yes, use [SetupDiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) to analyze the logs of the failed update.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - i haven't had a chance to try it - holiday weekend spent with the family :-) - will try it this week i hope.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft never tests Windows Upgrade (the Feature Updates of Windows 10 are new Windows version, so the update is doing an upgrade like Vista to 7 or 7 to 8) when a different boot loader is used.

When I did the upgrade from 1607 to 1709 on my 8" Toshiba Encore Tablet, I also needed to disable the Android x86 boot entry otherwise the setup also failed. I submitted it to Microsoft so try the [1803 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)/[Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) if they improved it now.

If this also fails and [running SetupDiag to analyze the log files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) [uninstall GRUB](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/), update to 1803 and [reinstall GRUB boot loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686049).

Comment: I will try this today I hope ...