# How do i renable connecting a network drive using SMB1 since Windows 1709

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, smb, readynas

I find today that I can no longer mount my Netgear ReadyNas drive because apparently it is using *SMB1* and Windows 10 have disabled since release 1709. This is very problemaic because I need to access these files and because I have lost the admin password for the ReadyNas itself so I cannot login in order to update/reconfigure it to use SMB2 instead.

Microsoft refers me  to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows which in turn refers me to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and if I really want re-enable SMB1

And I successfully did re-enable SMB1 by running

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName smb1protocol
```

from Powershell as Adminstrator.

However even after reboot I still cannot re-establish connection to my Netgear from Windows Explorer, it gives the same error

What else do I need to do ?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online –FeatureName SMB1Protocol


FeatureName      : SMB1Protocol
DisplayName      : SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support
Description      : Support for the SMB 1.0/CIFS file sharing protocol and the Computer Browser protocol.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Support for the SMB 1.0/CIFS file sharing protocol and the Computer
                   Browser protocol.
                   ServerComponent\DisplayName : SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support
                   ServerComponent\Id : 487
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : FS-SMB1
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : SMB1Protocol
```

**Solution**

Thanks Bob, *SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support* was enabled but within it *SMB 1.0 Client* **was not enabled**, checking that box and rebooting fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you go to Programs and Features (old Control Panel) => Turn Windows Features on or off (left sidebar) and check if `SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support` is enabled (checked) in that list? https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpUS1.png from the second MS Support link.

Comment: Also see what `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online –FeatureName SMB1Protocol` says.

Comment: simple solution, get [older Win10 version (1607) ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), use Rufus to create a WinToGo on an USB connected HDD, boot that WinToGo and access the NAS here over SMB1 and get all data

Comment: Thnakyou @Bob that was basically the issue , see my updated question with solution.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Please add that as a self-answer below rather than editing it into the question.

Comment: @Bob okay, have done that.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Great! :) Now you just need to wait a couple days and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Bob, thank you! All I had to do was enable SMB support as you stated in your first comment and then reboot. This was for a Synology DS416Play NAS in Windows 10 Pro 1809.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that although I had sucessfully reinstalled SMB1, the SMB1 client had not been enabled, so if you hit this problem there are two stages.

*First Reinstall SMB1.0*

- In Task bar search for *Windows Powershell* then *Run as Administrator*
- Run *Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName smb1protocol*
- Reboot

*Now re-enable Client Support*

- In Taskbar search for *Control Panel* and start it
- Select *Program and Features*
- Select *Turn Windows Features On and Off* on the top left handside
- Find *SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support* in list
- Click on the *+* button to expand
- Ensure all three SMB options are enabled
- Click *OK*
- Reboot