# my omninas kd 20 has stopped working due to windows 10 not supporting SMB1 anymore.

Tags: drivers

since upgrading to windows 10 64 bit my omninas kd20 nas backup has stopped working. Windows needs SMB2 or higher but the nas drive uses SMB1. How can I get this working again please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i renable connecting a network drive using SMB1 since Windows 1709](https://superuser.com/questions/1318769/how-do-i-renable-connecting-a-network-drive-using-smb1-since-windows-1709)

Answer (score 3):

here are two common workarounds if we disable SMBv1.

one is that we can start the "Function Discovery Provider Host" and "Function Discovery Resource Publication" services, and then set them to Automatic (Delayed Start).
When you open Explorer Network, enable network discovery when you are prompted.

another one is that we can try use map drive.

But,for some application and device manufacturer, above workarounds can't work. And what we can do is enabling SMBv1.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server