# How to fix Windows 10 update failure loop on low free space HDDs?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, tablet

Got a headache with my Windows 10 tablet. It's the Tesco Connect 9 (32gb HDD 1GB RAM)

The update takes almost 3 hours to finish installing. When the tab reboots, I hit

"There isn't enough memory available to create a ramdisk device”

Error Code 0xc0000017"

As soon as I get back into Windows, the process begins again. The update starts, installs and fails.

Any pointers?

Comment: download the [1803 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), connect an USB hub to the tablet, store the content of the ISO on 1 USB flash drive and attach a 2nd empty USB drive. now run setup.exe from the 1st USB drive and upgrade, during upgrade , select the empty drive as temp drive.

Comment: You're a genius.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

For devices with less mass storage you need to do some steps on your own:

- download the [1803 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)
- connect an USB hub to the tablet, store the content of the ISO on 1 USB flash drive and attach a 2nd empty USB drive.
- now run `setup.exe` from the 1st USB drive and upgrade, during upgrade , select the empty drive as temp drive.

[image]