# Windows needs space for update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows update needs space for update, but my C:\Windows folder is already eating up 57,3Gb on my 128Gb SSD. I also have about 3Gb left available on the drive, and Windows Update doesn't tell me how much space it needs, just "we need more space".

I have stripped my C: drive of everything I could, and I don't know what to do now... Is there a way to download the update to my other drive which has 400Gb of free space, or something like that ?

Comment: What is *I have stripped my C: drive of everything I could*? Please be specific.

Comment: Do you have drive compression on? - you probably need it with only a 128GB drive

Comment: As a general thumbrule MS suggests that you have 50GB free. I have rarely seen it need that much but 10GB is not unusual.

Comment: Move all the personal data you can to the other drive.

Comment: Have you done a proper disk cleanup? Any temp files, downloads, and windows.old folders will consume space quickly. Also, do you use hibernate? Learn how to turn that off and delete that file, it gets rather large over time.

Comment: [use 2 USB thumb drives to upgrade to 1803](https://superuser.com/a/1324429/174557). use treesizefree to detect folders with a lot of space usage and move data to other drive.

Comment: Move your swap file to the hard drive.

Comment: @JanDoggen removed everything I didn't absolutely *need*

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I removed all temp files, bin is empty, I see no windows.old (but I'm aware of its existence from the upgrade from win7 to win10 so looked for it). What is hibernate ? Is it the thing to start up quickly that doesn't really turn the PC off when you press Shut Down ? I don't know whether it is on or not, but it should get emptied when you restart anyway, shouldn't it ?

Comment: So it looks like you did not run Disk Cleanup. If someone asks you to explain *everything* do not answer with *everything* and vague descriptions *need*

Comment: @JanDoggen I did run a disk cleanup. I don't *need* temporary files and such

Answer (score 0):

There is an ever-ongoing discussion about if compression makes the system faster or slower, but it definitely saves space.
So compress your complete C: drive (ignore files that come up as locked), do your update, and then uncompress if you don't want it permanently.