# down-grade from Windows 10 LTSB to Windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10

I have a pc with windows 10 enterprice LTSB installed, can I install over it licensed win 10 home without data-wiping (save ALL data with accaunts programs and etc.)?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish. Do you want to keep all installed programs, settings and user accounts?

Comment: with regedit edit the value EditionID under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mifrosoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion** to **Core**, get [1803 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557), mount ISO run setup.exe and select "keep everything" (apps & data). this works for Win7 to downgrade, but I have no idea if this still works for Win10.

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just install home version via usb over LTSB and saved all in windows.old, then I copy'ed my data from .old dir and paste'ed into folders, all is work correctly!