# Download ISO file for Installing the LATEST version of Windows 10 into VirtualBox - and also download the upgrade?

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image

First some background... 
I installed the upgraded (May 2019) version of Windows 10 to a Dell computer. I used Microsoft's MediaCreationTool1903.exe for that, which I already had.

Then I installed VirtualBox into my fresh Windows 10 installation.

Into VirtualBox, I installed a Linux distro and it works but with aspect ratio problems that I don't want to deal with.

So I am planning to install Windows 10 into this VB.

I purchased a Windows 10 license key, and went to download Windows 10 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10 .

As you'll see, it offers a download of the Windows 10 upgrade at the top of the page.

And it also offers a download for Create Windows 10 Installation Media. Is this download what I already have, i.e. MediaCreationTool1903.exe ?

I think the Create Windows 10 Installation Media is what I need. Am I right? I think so because the page says that's the way to get the ISO for Windows 10.

I'm stumped at this point because what I will want to run inside VB is the recent UPGRADED version of Windows 10.

Step 7 of the instructions here https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10 for creating installation media do remind you to get updates, but these appear to be for device drivers. Not for Windows 10.

Will I be able to install the LATEST Windows 10 into my VB if the file I get by choosing Download Create Installation Media is not a file for the latest Windows 10? Or will it be?

Now that I've written all this, I think perhaps that's my primary question...

...Is the Create Installation Media file I'm currently downloading going to give me 1) an ISO of 2) the latest version of Windows 10?

What file do you get when you download the upgrade?

What file do you get when you download the Create Installation Media file? I hope it isn't MediaCreationTool1903.exe because I already have that. The page I link to in this post provides instructions for creating the ISO from the Create Installation Media download... but is this going to be for the LATEST version of Windows 10?

Does the Create Installation Media file eliminate any need to also download the other option... namely to also download the upgrade?

If I do have to upgrade to get an ISO for the most recent version of Windows 10, how do I do that?

Again, the two options discussed above are available here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)

Comment: “Is this download what I already have?” - Yes; When you ran it you were given two options.  One to perform the upgrade the other to download the ISO (in order to create a bootable installation media).  The version of the Media Creation Tool you have only downloads 1903.  “If I do have to upgrade to get an ISO for the most recent version of Windows 10, how do I do that?” - You are already running the current version of Windows 10 (1903) there isn’t another version to upgrade to

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I did get MediaCreationTool1903.exe again (from the download).

Comment: “but is this going to be for the LATEST version of Windows 10?” - Yes; The 1903 Media Creation Tool downloads Windows 10 version 1903.  Likewise, The 1809 Media Creation Tool (which is no longer available) would download Windows 10 version 1809.