# Is it possible to upgrade from 1803 to 1809?

Tags: windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

I'm trying to upgrade from 1803 to 1809. In the Windows Update there are no updates, I've clicked "Check for updates" a couple of times. Is it possible to upgrade to 1809 somehow? I've found WindowsUpdateTool on the official site, but it's for 1903.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to upgrade to 1809 somehow?

Yes; It is possible (yesterday, today and tommorow) to upgrade to 1809 if you have 1803 installed.  You will have to download a [Windows 10 1809 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10) in order to acomplish this.

Since the Upgrade Assistant and Media Creation Tool have both been upgrade to 1903, downloading the ISO, is the only method you can use.

> I've found WindowsUpdateTool on the official site, but it's for 1903.

Please be aware that in a very short amount of time (releative) 1809 will not actually be supported.