# If Windows 10 came preinstalled on my machine, can I reinstall using a windows DVD?

Tags: windows-installation, windows-10-v1803

I need to downgrade from 1903 to 1803. Since I updated over 2 months ago the only option I have is a brand new install from an iso file. The question is, if I use this iso file can I put in my OEM Windows product key or will it not work? I cannot use the fresh install because it would still have 1903 and this causes my system to crash.

Comment: It's possible that a brand new install is not your only option. In fact I would advise against it. Nowadays computers and notebooks come with a recovery method that allows the user to easily restore the OS from factory without the need of any DVD.  Users usually lose this capability when they format the PC using a DVD without knowing about it. Have you checked if your system has this feature?

Comment: 1803 and 1809 are the buggiest versions of Windows10 ever released. Highly recommend going up to 1909!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If Windows 10 came preinstalled on my machine, can I reinstall using a Windows DVD?

A Windows 10 allows you to install any version of that edition on your machine.  Since there is no concept of an "OEM" Windows 10 ISO, you can use a retail Windows 10 ISO, to install an OEM installation.  **When prompted for the product key all you have to do to install Windows is skip entering the product key.**

> The question is if I use this iso file can I put in my OEM Windows product key or will it not work?

It absolutely will work.

> I cannot use the fresh install because it would still have 1903 and this causes my system to crash.

You can simply download a Windows 10 version 1803 ISO [directly from Microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10).  I won't suggest which method you use to download the ISO, but all the linked solutions, **download the ISO directly from Microsoft**.

The only times you will be limited to Windows 10 version 1903 is if you use the Media Creation Tool or the Upgrade Assistant.  If you find yourself installing Windows 10 more than once a year, you should keep a version of each tool for the version you want to download, available to be used.  **Existing copies of the tool will download whatever version of Windows 10 they were released for.**

Worth pointing out that downgrading to 1803 will require you to perform a clean Windows 10 install.  Windows 10 only supports upgrading to a feature update that is newer.  There is a limit on the number of feature upgrades you can skip, I had problems trying to upgrade 1507 and 1511 to a newer upgrade (it would fail during the process), I was forced to upgrade to 1607 before newer upgrades would work.

Windows 10 Professional version 1803 will reach the end of Service on [November 12, 2019.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) I suggest you upgrade to Windows 10 version 1809 instead which will give you until May 2020 to figure a solution to your Windows 10 version 1903 compatibility issues.

Answer (score -1):

The OEM license is tied to the machine and the licensing is held in the Microsoft Licensing server.

If you wish to reinstall (vs. Repair Install), use the Microsoft Media Creation Link and keep nothing

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

V1803 is old enough that you cannot go back.

Comment: If I do that won't it give me Windows with 1903 since that is what the machine is running? I need 1803 which is unavailable through microsoft.com

Comment: Maybe you could let us know what is causing V1903 to crash.

Comment: Yes on bleepingcomputer.com forums I was told that my problem is well known for Toshiba's. The solution was a downgrade to 1803. The 1903 version causes a dpc watchdog violation causing the os to crash quite often.

Comment: Did you try updating the Toshiba BIOS followed by updating all drivers.  That can often help with Windows crashing

Comment: Everything up to date. Do you know if I use the OEM product key will the installer allow me to use this?

Comment: You can try. You have a good license, so try the installer and see if it works

Comment: @Jinzu - If you attempt to enter a Windows 10 OEM product key, in any Windows 10 installer, the product key will be rejected.  That does not mean, the installation will not activate, in fact, it will activate automatically since the key is detected automatically.

Comment: "V1803 is old enough that you cannot go back." Such nonsense.......https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10

Comment: @Moab - The inaccuracy of this answer is the reason i felt I needed to submit an accurate answer to his question