# How to clean install Windows 10 with a product or license key?

Tags: windows-10, license, pxe, license-key, winpe

I'm considering buying a PC which comes with Windows preinstalled; typically I run Linux.

If I were to format the hard drive and install Linux so that Windows was removed from the hard drive, just note the license key?  Just keep or re-use the output from:  `wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey` and then re-activate?

Assuming no hardware changes, as that [seems](https://superuser.com/q/1541234/55747) to be a factor.

Pardon, not sure whether it's a retail or OEM license -- nor the specific version of Windows 10.  (Just buying from Amazon, newish desktop PC.)

Comment: Windows 10 is already activated on OEM hardware there will absolutely never be an instance where you will need the Windows 10 product key.  It’s not required to reinstall it, and given the hardware you want to product there isn’t any hardware that will every require you to reactivate your installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1241948/windows-10-digital-license-after-pc-format/1241952#1241952 and https://superuser.com/questions/1484272/recovery-windows-10-home-key/1484285#1484285

Comment: I don't know @Ramhound as it's a hypothetical at this point.  Doing my research to try and understand the pitfalls here.

Comment: If you are actually purchasing a computer, that has Windows 10 installed on it, there will never be a reason you will need the product key.  **Windows 10 activation is automatic.**

Comment: Please note that I am not an expert on Windows licensing (how it really works) and also not a legal expert. My below comment is purely experimental suggestion. I may be totally wrong. So, use your discretion before implementing it. An OEM Windows 10 license may be pre-activated on a hardware. However, once your new PC arrives, do not connect it to the Internet. The moment you connect it to the Internet it will auto-activate. First, using the command you mentioned or any other third-party tool fetch the OEM key and make a note of it. Continued....

Comment: Now wipe the HDD and proceed with Linux installation. Now you may connect that PC to the Internet. On another PC/Laptop install the matching edition of Windows 10 i.e. if your PC that you newly bought came with ‘Home’ then install Windows 10 Home on that another PC. Now connect it to the Internet and use your OEM key to see if it activates and then binds itself to that hardware. This will surely not work if Microsoft maintains a record of hardware hash and OEM key being tied together for an OEM pre-configured Windows 10 PC on their activation servers and uses both for verification. Continued..

Comment: In case this works, I still can not comment if it’s legally correct or if you actually are violating any of the clauses of Windows 10 EULA.

Comment: exactly, @patkim you've addressed my concern.  I'd like some degree of legitimate portability here with a license or key that's at least registered to me.  However, that doesn't *seem* to be how it works.

Comment: OEM keys are not portable, they are tied to the hardware sold.  A retail key can be moved to new hardware or virtual hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is whether having wiped out Windows 10, how to reinstall it.

If the PC came with an OEM license, then `OA3xOriginalProductKey` will display it.
If it displays as blank, then the license is not OEM and can be retrieved by
a product such as
[ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html).

The license key might also be contained in a sticker on the computer case.

In many cases, and especially when upgrading to Windows 10 from a previous version,
you will not have a product key. Instead, the PC gets registered on Microsoft
activation servers with a digital license (formerly called digital entitlement)
that can always be used to activate Windows 10 on that PC, as long as the
hardware hash does not change excessively.
The "key" is then a generic one that cannot be used for re-activation.

You need to carefully examine the situation and decide on the best method for
conserving the key. I suggest to also google your key, to find if this is only
a generic one. For a generic key, the hardware hash is the real key for Microsoft.

Comment: What is a generic key?  I'll have to look into that one.  Very informative.

Comment: A generic key is one that is shared by millions of computers worldwide. It's basically a placeholder, with the real activation actually recorded on the Microsoft servers, where your computer is identified by its hardware hash.