# How do i completely clean reinstall windows 10 home? I want the pc to be fresh deleting all the current graphics drivers that i wrongly installed

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, reset

I have installed wrong graphics drivers on my brand new windows 10 laptop. The driver situation is really messed up and there are a ton of other bugs and errors throught the system. I dont wanna reset it as i believe it will keep some of the current drivers(Isnt it?). I wanna fully clean install windows 10.I tried doing this with the windows media creation tool but ended up with a 0x80072f76 – 0x20016 error.

Comment: *deleting all the current graphics drivers that i wrongly installed* Boot in VGA mode, and delete driver's INF file(s). Then reboot and install correct driver. It is enough in most cases.

Comment: See this page....https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh

Answer (score 0):

> I dont wanna reset it as i believe it will keep some of the current drivers(Isnt it?).

You can perform a Reset and choose not to keep anything.  This would have the exact same effect of doing a clean install.

[image]

You can also use Start Fresh

[image]

> I wanna fully clean install windows 10.

You will need a [Windows 10 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10).  In process could not be easier, you download the ISO, then boot to the installation environment.

> I tried doing this with the windows media creation tool but ended up with a 0x80072f76 – 0x20016 error.

Sounds like a hardware or software conflict.  Of course your driver problem can be solved by doing a clean install of the driver itself.  Going through the process, even a simple process to reinstall Windows, is not required to solve your current problem.

Sources:

- [Start fresh with a clean installation of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh)
- [How to Easily Reinstall Windows 10 Without the Bloatware](https://www.howtogeek.com/265054/how-to-easily-reinstall-windows-10-without-the-bloatware/)
- [Everything You Need to Know About “Reset This PC” in Windows 8 and 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/132428/everything-you-need-to-know-about-refreshing-and-resetting-your-windows-8-pc/)