# Can someone please look at this log and tell me why Windows 7 Pro to 10 Pro is failing

Tags: windows

This is the log from the affected pc

0x800704B8 - 0X3001A FIRST_BOOT phase error

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_D8kRwZvK9CdP11GxQppXcwRYjNLutxV

Thank you

Comment: That is a huge log. What inferences have you drawn thus far?

Comment: There is a very long answer (not conclusive) here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/winows-update-error-0x800704b8-0x3001a/2c0978f9-bda3-4e4f-a498-7d2f80017c3a     Make sure BIOS and all Drivers are up to date.

Comment: Finally, if you think this older computer will run Windows 10, back up and install Windows 10 fresh.

Comment: Thanks, this is Dell Optiplex 7010, very common PC, I have it running on many other similar machines. Reason I am trying to resolve this (and not fresh install) because of complex software configuration on it.

Comment: Before I can submit an answer.  I need to know the size of your system reserved partition.  I also need to know how old your hardware is.  This might be a simple hardware incompatibility issue.

Comment: That machine was release 9 to 11 years ago. As I noted update BIOS, all Drivers, remove Anti Virus, Office and all except the complex software, restart and see if upgrade proceeds or you get a different block of errors.

Comment: Partition is 100MB, however it fails even is I ran /resizerecoverypartition enable

Comment: Windows 10 needs about 30GB (possibly more) free space to successfully update (Windows.old can be very large).

Comment: I thought you meant hidden small partition ,, there is 300GB of free space there. And I have Windows 10 running on Optiplex 7010 (upgraded) with no issues, but this one puzzles me

Comment: Somewhere comments vanished here. You said it had Office 2010 with numerous Outlook Accounts Office 2010 is at or nearly out of support. PST files can be saved and imported into newer Outlook if you finally get converted

Comment: it has no Office installed

Comment: Perform a clean boot in Windows 7, then try the upgrade again.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you trying to install?

Comment: I did try cleanboot, same error, installing 10 pro on top of 7 pro

Comment: `The Recovery Partition` != `System Reserve Partition`.  Why are you trying to change the size of your recovery partition?

Answer (score 1):

> failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]

Based on that error you can try the following:

1. Download [PSExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
2. Run the following command within an elevated command prompt

`PsExec.exe -s -i regedit.exe`

3. Export `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade`
4. Delete `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade`
5. Use Disk Cleanup to remove previous attempts.
6. Reset [Windows Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources)
7. Perform a reboot
8. Download a [Windows 10 version 1809 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)
9. Create a Windows 10 media installation disk.
10. From within Windows 7 launch the Windows 10 Setup.

Comment: If the above does not work, then you have a hardware conflict, and there is something else going on.  However, `Optiplex 7010` is specific enough, to provide the information required to diagnose it.  *The above steps are calculated, and each step, has a specific reason for doing it.*

Comment: thank you for trying to help, I did do steps 1-4, didn't do the rest, 1809 might be a good idea, however i will update bios on this machine to try the next step

Comment: You need to do at least through step 7 otherwise my suggestion won’t work