# New Windows10 rescue CD needed for a new build?

Tags: boot

Seems a simple question but I can't seem to google up the answer.

Can a rescue CD made in an older build of Windows10 be used in a new build, or are we meant to create new boot media  everytime there is a feature update?

Note I am talking purely about the boot media. Not a system image or a recovery partitionm.

I originally made a rescue CD in build 1809, and after recently updating to 1909 this question has occurred to me. Thank you.

Comment: Depends on what you are going to repair.

Comment: I think it can be used if needed, to fix errors, etc. However if you ever do need to use it, make sure you use Windows Update to upgrade all the files which might be needed, (may have been replaced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a rescue CD made in an older build of Windows10 be used in a new build, or are we meant to create new boot media everytime there is a feature update?

Short Answer: No

Longer Answer: It actually depends what you are doing within the WinRE.

In order to repair your installation from within the WinRE, it must have been created from the same version of the installation media, as the version of Windows 10 that is installed.

You can use an older version if you are attempting to create a required partition.

> I originally made a rescue CD in build 1809, and after recently updating to 1909 this question has occurred to me.

You really should update your installation media in the event you actually need to repair your image.  You wouldn’t be able to run DISM or SFC against a 1809 image of your 1909 were to become corrupt.

The entire process of creating installation media is almost automated.  You really should take a moment to update your media.  I actually recommend downloading the Media Creation Tool to install a feature update instead of downloading and installing it through Windows Update.

[Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10)