# Windows 10 "Turn Windows features on or off" (OptionalFeatures.exe) list blank

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was having permission errors in WSL so I thought I would disable and reennale WSL.

That didn't seem to help, and now the list of features under `Turn Windows features on or off` is blank and I cannot enable or disable Windows Features.

[image: OptionalFeatures.exe Blank]

When I run `sfc /scannow` it says `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.`

Answer (score 0):

> When I run `sfc /scannow` it says `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service`.

This is an indication of severe system corruption.  Additional evidence that your system is corrupt is the fact your unable to disable or enable, optional Windows Features.

At this point your only option to finish the problems you describe, in addition to your `Windows Subsystem for Linux` permission problems, is to perform an in-place repair install of the same version of Windows 10 you already installed.

Before you proceed with these instructions you should perform an adequate backup of all important files.  Performing an in-place repair installation of Windows is a solution that should be used if you have no other choice.  **Since you are unable to use the appropriate `SFC` and/or `DISM` commands to repair the system corruption, that does indeed appear to be the case.**

The specific problem is that your `WinSxS` (Windows Side by Side) assembly store is corrupt.  `WinSxS` is the directory that is used to install any optional Windows feature.  **Once this directory is corrupt, there isn't an easy way, to fix the corruption other than performing an in-place repair.**

1. Download the appropriate ISO using one of the resources listed in the question [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10).  **In order for this to be successfully you must download an ISO for the same edition, version and language you already have installed.**
2. Once you have the ISO right-click on the file and `Mount` the ISO.
3. Run **Setup.exe**
4. When prompted you should select **"Keep personal files and apps"**
5. Carefully follow all additional prompts.
6. Once the installation finishes you should update your system immediately.

[image]
[image]