# Windows10 upgrade: does WindowsUpgrade9252.exe always use latest version or the one that was current at the day this file was downloaded?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have two laptops with Win10 Pro, one with version 1809 and the other with 1909.

I upgraded the 1909 with the file *Windows10Upgrade9252.exe* like 6 weeks ago. With the occurring news about problems with the 2004 upgrade, I wanted to at least switch to 1909 with the second one. Sites like [cnet.com](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/new-to-windows-10-heres-how-long-microsoft-will-support-it/) state that 1809 patches just ended for end users. And I missed to upgrade one laptop before 2004 was made publicly available.

So while copying *Windows10Upgrade9252.exe* on my stick I discovered I have the same file already there - dating on april 2018 with a different file size.

Now my question is:

- Does this file *Windows10Upgrade9252.exe* always tries to install the latest upgrade available or the one it was meant to while downloading the file?
- Put otherway round: Can I use my *Windows10Upgrade9252.exe* from early May 2020 to get the 1909 upgrade while avoiding the 2004 upgrade?

My hidden goal is to get the "last but one" upgrade.
This question [about a specific iso](https://superuser.com/q/1108085/1000443) points to [https://tb.rg-adguard.net/](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php) - does that fulfill my hidden goal as well = I just need to get it installed from an USB with that 1909 iso on it? (As I do not iso installs that often I want to add: the currently installed programs need to stay installed, the licence kept etc. ...)

Comment: When a feature update is released the tool is updated.  When this happens the filename is updated to reflect that change.  You don’t actually need that tool to get a 1909 ISO.  You can download the ISO yourself, mount the ISO within Windows, and launch setup.exe and it will perform the upgrade to 1909 the exact same way as the Upgrade Assistant tool you have downloaded

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So your answer is: mount the iso and start the offered install, this will create an upgrade (to 1909) and keeping all data and programms as intact as 1909 can. So there is no need to reinstall any software, because it is still there? And the downloaded 6 MB file would do the same, just including the "iso download"(all needed files). So the filename of the upgrade file points to a specific version like 1909 or 2004?

Comment: Yes;  Each specific version of the Upgrade Assistant upgrades your system to the applicable version of Windows update.  If you want to upgrade to a specific version use the ISO instead of the tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mind to write an answer out of it? Best regards

Comment: I am getting ready for work.  If I have the time I absolutely will write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a full answer, the technically unclear/leftover part of my question is: How come it is a different file size when the name indicates the upgrade version?

User [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) commented that the tool gets an update with any upgrade - and the file name as well.

That implies that the same tool name should perform the same Windows Upgrade.

The main goal "install a specific Windows Upgrade version" however can be achieved with downloading an ISO, mount it and be fine. [see answer in related question](https://superuser.com/q/1108085/1000443)

Comment: unless there will be a technically full answer, I mark my as the one - because my goal that sparked that question could be achieved.