# Update windows to specifc major release

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a computer running windows 10 1903, and I want to update it to 1909. It doesn't show up in windows update, and I cant seem to find the 1909 update tool anymore, and only the 2004 one. I also figured out how to install update files directly by downloading the update files from windows, but I'm not sure what all i would need to install to go from 1903 to 1909.

I have tried checking my system and multiple ways to "fix" my windows update since nothing is showing up there, but none of that worked.

I currently cannot wipe this computer, so I cannot use the iso to install 1909.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: @Ramhound a little different because the original question was if there was a way to just update to that version specifically, but getting the iso was the solution, which would lead me to that thread on how to get the iso.

Comment: Isn't there a GPO for this? I set it to 1809 on my system and all feature updates since then have disappeared. https://www.ghacks.net/2020/06/27/you-can-now-set-the-target-windows-10-release-in-professional-versions/ - "If you specify a newer version, Windows 10 will move to that particular version and not another one, even if a newer version is available; that's great news for administrators who don't want systems to be upgraded to the latest feature update version of Windows 10."

Comment: @MuamerBektić - I don't see a huge difference, especially, if the solution is to download an ISO and mount it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows update will only let you to upgrade windows 10 to the latest build, which is currently 2004. So if you want to upgrade a 1903 machine to 1909, then you have to download the 1909 ISO first, and then re-install windows. Backup all valuable data before re-installation.

Download link: [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10/1108086#1108086)

Comment: @Tonny Thanks! That seemed to work. I tried 15 different things, and none went though several websites and none of them mentioned that the iso would just let you update. only downside is the full 5gb download, which over my currently required vpn took a long time.

Comment: @MuamerBektić if you don't want to download 5GB ISO, there is no many other ways. The x86 ISO is 3.5 GB, but installing it will let you to have up to 4 GB of RAM and no x64 application support. Also don't download various crack compressed files, they will download Trojan on your computer.