# Windows install fails

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

ALL,

I am trying to follow the instructions found [here](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/198427-how-to-install-windows-10-in-a-virtual-machine).

As the point 1 suggested, I went [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and downloaded the the Windows 10 VirtaulBox ISO.

However, trying to install it I'm getting the error:

[quote]

Something went wrong

You can try again or skip for now

OOBEREGION

[/quote]

Clicking `Try Again` I am coming back to the same screen. And clicking `Skip` it happens also. So I can't continue.

My question is - is there an MD5 checksum for an image I download from the MS WebSite? Or some other means to verify the download?

I am trying it on the VirtualBox installed on the Linux box (if it matters). I got 64-bit English Windows 10 ISO.

I am trying to create a VM on the newly bought external hard drive, 500GB ext3 partition. Since the drive is brand new I doubt its a hardware.

TIA!

[EDIT]

As requested:

```
IgorReinCloud /run/media/igor/24fbb29a-63fd-4e37-9c6c-ad61b47baadc # lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Wrestler HDMI Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at f0444000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 4118 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4124 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4110 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4120 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4100 [size=16]
    Memory at f044c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [70] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at f044b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    Memory at f044a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [e4] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00e0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0449000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    Memory at f0448000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [e4] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00e0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SBx00 SMBus Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0440000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: None
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None

00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f0300000-f03fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
    Capabilities: [b8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f0200000-f02fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
    Capabilities: [b8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:15.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: None
    Memory behind bridge: f0100000-f01fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
    Capabilities: [b8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [f0] Secure device <?>
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
    Flags: fast devsel

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [6c] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] Device Serial Number ff-ca-19-a6-1c-75-08-ff
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H167.00
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [60] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-15-17-ff-ff-24-14-12
    Capabilities: [170] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

IgorReinCloud /run/media/igor/24fbb29a-63fd-4e37-9c6c-ad61b47baadc # df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      460700400 43102928 394125412  10% /
devtmpfs           10240        0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs             787940     1084    786856   1% /run
shm              3939684    81188   3858496   3% /dev/shm
cgroup_root        10240        0     10240   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             3939684       36   3939648   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0       5144854  5144854         0 100% /mnt/iso
/dev/sdc1      515013048  9485024 479313624   2% /run/media/igor/24fbb29a-63fd-4e37-9c6c-ad61b47baadc
```

I think that should be all.

The failure occurs right before installation finishes and "Windows Welcome Screen" should show up.

[/EDIT]

Comment: At what part of the process are you getting the error? What are the specs of the host machine and what resources are you allocating to the VM?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10) might be helpful

Comment: Did you enable Hardware Virtualization (VT-x) in BIOS so that you can install virtual machines?

Comment: @John, this is not the first VM I'm trying to set up. So yes, everything is enabled.

Comment: @NasirRiley, the error comes up after the reboot. The preparation, copying and finalizing steps are done, then the VM rebooted and after some time this error comes up. And what do you mean by `specs of the host machine`? And I'm giving 4K of RAM and 500G of HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm trying to set it up on the host hard drive to check if its really a problem with the download or a drive. If it fails I might download the new install from the link you provided.

Comment: @Ramhound, so trying to create the VM on the host hard drive didn't work as well. I'll try to check the link you provided and see if I can get the good install from there.

Comment: Just like I said. The specs of the host machine where Virtualbox is installed. Add the information to your question so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: @NasirRiley, I added `lspci` and `df -k` output as an edit. I also added the place where the failure occurs

Comment: What do you mean you downloaded the Windows 10 Virtualbox ISO?  I don't think such a thing exists.  Do you mean you downloaded the Windows 10 ISO and are trying to install it on VirtualBox?  If so, be sure the virtualbox's nic can get to the internet.  Windows 10 requires internet access to complete its setup.

Comment: @mikem, yes, I downloaded Windows 10 ISO. And yes - VirtualBox does have Internet access - it uses NAT for that VM I tried.

Comment: @NasirRiley, did you see my edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps these instructions will help:
https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/ooberegion/

Comment: thank you. I don't know why you got downvoted....