# Reinstall win10 to Remove Possible Malware

Tags: windows-10, installation, malware-removal

I have a suspicion  my *Dell Latitude 7480* might have malware or another tracking hidden software, and I want to reinstall win 10.

I do not have an installation media but Windows is legit and digitally licensed.

From within Windows settings: System -> Recovery there is resetting windows (vs. reinstalling).

Questions:

1. Is resetting (that is reinstall win but keep personal files) good enough to remove all possible malwares and viruses if exist, or better backup everything, wipe and do clean install.
2. There is also an option to reset and NOT keeping files. Is it exactly like choosing reinstall?
3. After downloading and creating a USB, wheat needs to be done to reclaim the license for the new installation?

Comment: Have you  bothered to run anything like malwarebytes?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, nothing found.

Comment: If there is nothing found by malwarebytes.. and you have checked all of your startup items and services.. then you are probably wasting your time.  Modern systems from OEMs (like DELL) store the windows key via UEFI firmware so you don't need to worry about the actual key.  When you re-install.. windows magically figures out where the key came from.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas better wasting some time, than be sorry later. Can you refer questions 1,2 as well please?

Comment: Dear Sir, I don't have the answer to number one or two.. only guesses based on experience.  That is why I provided a comment and not an answer. :)  Good luck!  I mean it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is resetting (that is reinstall win but keep personal files) good enough to remove all possible malwares and viruses if exist, or better backup everything, wipe and do clean install.

**Performing a Reset within Windows performs the same steps that reinstalling Windows will perform.**  However, in either case, you are going to have to choose NOT to keep your personal files otherwise you would be just transferring the malware to the new installation.  If you don't have an ISO for the version of Windows 10 you are running you can download one [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10).

> There is also an option to reset and NOT keeping files. Is it exactly like choosing reinstall?

Yes

> After downloading and creating a USB, wheat needs to be done to reclaim the license for the new installation?

You have indicated Windows 10 is activated and has a digital entitlement.  **If you were to reinstall Windows 10 it would automatically activate.**  You can reinstall Windows 10, from within Windows, by mounting the ISO for the version of Windows 10 you wish to install.  Be sure you select the option NOT to keep any personal files otherwise you run the risk of transferring the malware to the new installation.

Source: [Windows Setup Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installation-process#-windowssetup-process)

> Is it possible a malware is actually on the Documents folder, and when copying it back will cause the fresh installation be actually infected again?

Yes;  This is the reason I specifically indicated you should NOT keep any personal files.  However, you are the one who believes you are infected with malware, despite security software, saying you are not actually infected.  However, you are the best person, to determine what risks you are willing to accept.

Comment: @OJNSim - It's also based on years of experience. I personally don't use ESET products.  However, my opinion of ESET, has nothing to do with my answer.  My suggestion of not keeping any personal files stands.  I have never heard of a single infection that would extract `install.wim`, modify the image and replace it, in an effort to prevent from being removed.  **In order to modify a windows image the Windows SDK tool must be installed, the chances of malware modifying the image, is less than winning the lottery.**  You have better chances of being hit by lighting multiple times.

Comment: weird..some previous comments disappeared. Anyway, I am not arguing anything, just asking. Your explanation about malware is able to infect any kind of file is new to me, and I still wonder how to handle it. OS, Applications can be reinstalled from scratch maybe unconvinient but tolerable. Personal files - this is a real problem. I understand ESET is not good enough in your eyes, is there another one(s) that you feel can do a good job scanning all these files?